# Optimize code for adding data to a DataGridView

Tags: c++

I have a loop that executes a large number of times (say 25000). Inside the loop there is a code to add a row to a DataGridView.

`dvg->Rows->Add();`

Complete code below:

```
    for(int i = 0 ; i < m_Items->Length ; i++)
        {
            dgv->Rows->Add(); 

            dgv->Rows[i]->Cells[this->IDColumn->Index]->Value = safe_cast<System::Object^>(0);

            dgv->Rows[i]->Cells[this->ModColumn->Index]->Value = <<"Data from database">>

            dgv->Rows[i]->Cells[this->RunColumn->Index]->Value = <<"Data from database">>
        }
```

This statement is taking a couple of seconds to execute 25000 times. So I am trying to optimize this code for time.

I know the number of rows prior to entering the loop. So I thought moving this call out of the loop and call a function that will add 25000 rows at once. I searched online and this is what I tried so far.

I tried using **DataGridView::AddRange** function by passing a **DataGridViewRow** object as an argument. But the sample code found online is confusing. Since I am new to C# code, I don't know how to proceed.

I declared

`DataGridViewRow Test;`

Now, how to write the code that tells, the columns in **DataGridView** need to be same as the columns in dvg (If that is even required)?

Do I have to fill the data to `test` before calling **DataGridView::AddRange**?

Can somebody help, please?

Comment: Have you considered adding the rows to a `DataTable` then use the `DataTable` as a `DataSource` to the grid? How is the code getting the data in the first place? Point being, you should use a `DataSource` to populate the grid as opposed to “manually” adding the rows in code.

Comment: This question is confusing... you need to add the code you are using. It's weird that you are tagging C# but using C++ pointer syntax (`dvg->Rows->Add();`), or those C++-like namespaces (which could be c# aliases, but seems weird), like `DataGridView::AddRange`. Please show the code in particular that you want to change

Comment: @JohnG I haven't tried it yet. I was not aware that it is possible. In the code the add () function is called in the beginning of the loop, then below some code is there to fill the data that the application read from a database. Ex: dvg->Rows[i]->Cells[Index]->Value = "Some data from database";

Comment: @jcl : I was also confused with the tag. This is managed C++ code, but I thought of putting C# tag, because if I mention C++ tag and talk about DataGridView etc, it may be more confusing. My bad. I will change the tag to C++

Comment: I think this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516622/what-does-vectorization-mean#:~:text=Vectorization%20means%20that%20the%20compiler,%5D%20%2B%20b%5Bi%5D%3B%20%7D