# Vectorization of multi-level indexing of structs in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Say I have the following in MATLAB:

```
a(1).b.c = 4;
a(2).b.c = 5;
a(3).b.c = 7;
....
```

I would like to collect the values `[4 5 7 ...]` in a single array, without looping and in a vectorized manner.

I have tried:

```
>> a(:).b.c 
# Error: Scalar index required for this type of multi-level indexing.
```

and

```
>> a.b.c
# Error: Dot name reference on non-scalar structure.
```

but they didn't work. The best I could come up with was:

```
arrayfun(@(x) x.b.c, a);
```

but as far as I understand `arrayfun` is [not vectorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422149/what-is-vectorization), or is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a.b` returns multiple outputs, so you can't expect to call a function on it. The best one-liner I can think of without using `arrayfun` is:

```
y = subsref([a.b], substruct('.', c));
```

Note that `a.b.c` is effectively the same as:

```
y = subsref(a.b, substruct('.', c))
```

Which is why it shouldn't work for non-scalar `a`.

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `arrayfun` seems idiomatic enough to me in Matlab. I don't think this is vectorized but it's well optimized and maybe the fastest way.
You should also try to benchmark with a loop to see if the JIT compiler performs well here. It's hard to know without testing.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in two lines:

```
>> s = [a.b];
>> y = [s.c]
y =
     4     5     7
```

Another possible one-liner (less readable!):

```
>> y = squeeze(cell2mat( struct2cell([a.b]) ))
y =
     4
     5
     7
```