# What are some good ways to emulate cascading indexing in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

E.g. I would like to do things such as:

```
A=4:20;
find(A>5)(2) % want to access the 2nd element of the index array returned by find
```

Comment: I just thought of an alternative solution, and updated my answer.  Anyway, it's certainly not the first time something similar has been asked, but... http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this [comes up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it) [fairly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143854/matlab-alternative-to-creating-an-extra-vector) [frequently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743586/how-do-i-extract-matrix-elements-in-matlab/3743686#3743686) in [different contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878534/vectorization-of-multi-level-indexing-of-structs-in-matlab/7887315#7887315), and the one-line answer is `subsref`.  For your case, it is this:

```
subsref(find(A>5),struct('type','()','subs',{{2}}))
```

A much cleaner solution uses an undocumented `builtin`:

```
builtin('_paren',find(A>5),2)
```

**As an alternative to ugly syntax or undocumented functionality**, you could define a small function like the following,

```
function outarray = nextind(inarray,inds)
outarray = inarray(inds);
```

Or an inline function:

```
nextind = @(v,ii) v(ii);
```

And call it like `nextind(find(A>5),2)`.  This is cleaner than `subsref` and good if you are doing linear indexing (not subscripts).

Comment: Not helpful, I guess.  Oh, well

Comment: hmm yeah I don't understand the -1 either. I wish the person who downvoted added a comment. Anyway, thanks for your answer!

Comment: It's probably because of the duplication factor... but that's why I added all the links and an alternate solution.