# Chaining of matrix operations with indexing in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Doesn't Matlab allow chaining of matrix operations with indexing?

For eg.:

```
a = [1 2; 3 4];
exp(a)(:)
```

throws the error

```
Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.
```

It seems like this is something I would have expected Matlab to have or is there a different way to do this?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Ahh yes, definitely duplicate! :) Not sure what the correct course of action is in this scenario. Should I pull down my question?

Comment: Not unless you want to, the other questions will be referenced.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/19306017/2778484.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the indexing colon. The below should work.

```
a = [1 2; 3 4];
exp(a);
```