# Bypass delays when switching execution unit domains

Tags: assembly, intel, sse

I'm trying to understand possibly bypass delays when switching domains of execution units.

For example, the following two lines of code give exactly the same result.

```
_mm_add_ps(x, _mm_castsi128_ps(_mm_slli_si128(_mm_castps_si128(x), 8)));
_mm_add_ps(x, _mm_shuffle_ps(_mm_setzero_ps(), x, 0x40));
```

Which line of code is better to use?

The assembly output for the first line gives:

```
vpslldq xmm1, xmm0, 8
vaddps  xmm0, xmm1, xmm0
```

The assembly output for the second line gives:

```
vshufps xmm1, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rcx], 64   ; 00000040H
vaddps  xmm2, xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rcx]
```

Now if I look at Agner Fog's microarchitecture [manual](http://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf) he gives an example on page 112 of using a integer shuffle (pshufd) on float values versus using a float shuffle (shufps) on float values.  Switching domains adds 4 extra clock cycles so the solution using shufps is better.

The first line of code I listed using `_mm_slli_si128` has to switch domains between integer and float vectors.  The second using `_mm_shuffle_ps` stays in the same domain.  Doesn't this imply that the second line of code is the better solution?

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking this?

Comment: No, not yet.  But I have some code to do it with.  If you want to see why I'm interested see the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19494114/parallel-prefix-cumulative-sum-with-sse) and the prefix_sum_SSE function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Section 2.1.4 in the Intel [optimization guide](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/manual/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf) indicates that you (and Agner) are quite right on this matter -

> When a source of a micro-op executed in one stack comes from a micro-op executed in another stack, a one- or two-cycle delay can occur. **The delay occurs also for tran-sitions between Intel SSE integer and Intel SSE floating-point operation.**

[image]

So in general it seems you'd be better off keeping within the same stack/domain as much as possible.

Of course benchmarking is always preferred, and all this is worth handling only in case this is indeed a bottleneck in your code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  In my current case it does not make a difference in performance but I was mostly interesting in having a discussion on the subject since I'm still learning about it.