# OpenMP SIMD reduction with custom operator

Tags: c++, openmp, simd, avx

I have the following loop that I'd like to accelerate using `#pragma omp simd`:

```
#define N 1024
double* data = new double[N];
// Generate data, not important how.

double mean = 0.0
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    mean += (data[i] - mean) / (i+1);
}
```

As I expected, just putting `#pragma omp simd` directly before the loop has no impact (I'm examining running times).  I can tackle the multi-threaded case easily enough using `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(...)` with a custom reducer as shown below, but how do I put OpenMP SIMD to use here?

I'm using the following class for implementing the + and += operators for adding a `double` to a running mean as well as combining two running means:

```
class RunningMean {
    private:
        double mean;
        size_t count;

    public:
        RunningMean(): mean(0), count(0) {}
        RunningMean(double m, size_t c): mean(m), count(c) {}

        RunningMean operator+(RunningMean& rhs) {
            size_t c = this->count + rhs.count;
            double m = (this->mean*this->count + rhs.mean*rhs.count) / c;
            return RunningMean(m, c);
        }

        RunningMean operator+(double rhs) {
            size_t c = this->count + 1;
            double m = this->mean + (rhs - this->mean) / c;
            return RunningMean(m, c);
        }

        RunningMean& operator+=(const RunningMean& rhs) {
            this->mean = this->mean*this->count + rhs.mean*rhs.count;
            this->count += rhs.count;
            this->mean /= this->count;
            return *this;
        }

        RunningMean& operator+=(double rhs) {
            this->count++;
            this->mean += (rhs - this->mean) / this->count;
            return *this;
        }

        double getMean() { return mean; }
        size_t getCount() { return count; }
};
```

The maths for this comes from http://prod.sandia.gov/techlib/access-control.cgi/2008/086212.pdf.
For multi-threaded, non-SIMD parallel reduction I do the following:

```
#pragma omp declare reduction (runningmean : RunningMean : omp_out += omp_in)
RunningMean mean;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(runningmean:mean)
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    mean += data[i];
```

This gives me a 3.2X speedup on my Core i7 2600k using 8 threads.

If I was to implement the SIMD myself without OpenMP, I would just maintain 4 means in a vector, 4 counts in another vector (assuming the use of AVX instructions) and keep on adding 4-element double precision vectors using a vectorised version of `operator+(double rhs)`.  Once that is done, I would add the resulting 4 pairs of means and counts using the maths from `operator+=`.  How can I instruct OpenMP to do this?

Comment: Your custom reducer has recursion, that I guess the pragma cannot solve... What about: `mean += data[i] / N`?

Comment: @GHL This method of calculating the mean gives one a running total which can then be used in other methods, e.g. for variance that give a running variance, i.e. variance after `i` iterations.  Have a look at this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Rapid_calculation_methods).  For variance, this works out to be more numerically stable than the normal textbook definition, which is why I'm interested in it.

Comment: Understood, but how do you want the SIMD to speed up your calculation, as to compute each running sum (ie each iteration of the loop) you need the result of the previous one? I would say that for SIMD to work you need your calculations to be independent?

Comment: Can you please explain how can "tackle the multi-threaded case easily enough using #pragma omp parallel for reduction(...) with a custom reducer"? I would like to see that.

Comment: @chippies: can you present the code you *actually* wrote and it failed?

Comment: I've added more code showing how the multi-threaded parallel reduction works.  Sorry, I forgot most people don't calculate the mean of a sequence of numbers this way.

Comment: @chippies, have you verified that the parallel version gets the same result as the serial version?

Comment: Yes I have.  The results are the same up to 12 decimal places which is fine.

Comment: @chippies, okay, I'm missing something. Openmp creates private copies of `mean` for each thread which it will initialize the counts and mean to zero for each private copy. I don't see how it handle the dependency correctly. You can use the value your reducing in the reduction itself. They only get merged at the end.

Comment: @Zboson Here's my understanding: at the start of each thread, a private copy of `mean` gets created with `mean.mean=0` and `mean.count=0`.  That thread loops over a subset of the N array elements executing `mean += data[i]`, producing a `mean` with some value in `mean.mean` and the number of elements processed in `mean.count`.  That private copy of `mean` goes into the reduction, where the += operator for two `RunningMean` objects gets used.  Even if only a single entry from `data` gets into the private copy of `mean` before that copy goes to the reduction, the maths still works correctly.

Comment: @chippies, okay, I tested it. It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that

```
mean += (data[i] - mean) / (i+1);
```

is not easily amenable to SIMD. However, by studying the math carefully it's possible to vectorized this without too much effort.

The key forumla is

```
mean(n+m) = (n*mean(n) + m*mean(m))/(n+m)
```

which shows how to add the means of `n` numbers and the mean of `m` numbers. This can be seen in your operator definition `RunningMean operator+(RunningMean& rhs)`. This explains why your parallel code works. I think this is more clear if we deconvolute your C++ code:

```
double mean = 0.0;
int count = 0;
#pragma omp parallel
{
    double mean_private = 0.0;
    int count_private = 0;
    #pragma omp for nowait
    for(size_t i=0; i<N; i++) {
        count_private ++;
        mean_private += (data[i] - mean_private)/count_private;
    }
    #pragma omp critical
    {
        mean = (count_private*mean_private + count*mean);
        count += count_private;
        mean /= count;
    }
}
```

But we can use the same idea with SIMD (and combine them together). But let's first do the SIMD only part. Using AVX we can handle four parallel means at once. Each parallel mean will handle the following data elements:

```
mean 1 data elements: 0,  4,  8, 12,...
mean 2 data elements: 1,  5,  9, 13,...
mean 3 data elements: 2,  6, 10, 14,...
mean 4 data elements: 3,  7, 11, 15,...
```

One we have looped over all the elements then we add the four parallel sums together and divide by four (since each sum runs over N/4 elements).

Here is the code to to this

```
double mean = 0.0;
__m256d mean4 = _mm256_set1_pd(0.0);
__m256d count4 = _mm256_set1_pd(0.0);
for(size_t i=0; i<N/4; i++) {
    count4 = _mm256_add_pd(count4,_mm256_set1_pd(1.0));
    __m256d t1 = _mm256_loadu_pd(&data[4*i]);
    __m256d t2 = _mm256_div_pd(_mm256_sub_pd(t1, mean4), count4);
    mean4 = _mm256_add_pd(t2, mean4);   
}
__m256d t1 = _mm256_hadd_pd(mean4,mean4);
__m128d t2 = _mm256_extractf128_pd(t1,1);
__m128d t3 = _mm_add_sd(_mm256_castpd256_pd128(t1),t2);
mean = _mm_cvtsd_f64(t3)/4;
int count = 0;
double mean2 = 0;
for(size_t i=4*(N/4); i<N; i++) {
    count++;
    mean2 += (data[i] - mean2)/count;
}
mean = (4*(N/4)*mean + count*mean2)/N;
```

Finally, we can combine this with OpenMP to get the full benefit of SIMD and MIMD like this

```
double mean = 0.0;
int count = 0;
#pragma omp parallel 
{
    double mean_private = 0.0;
    int count_private = 0;
    __m256d mean4 = _mm256_set1_pd(0.0);
    __m256d count4 = _mm256_set1_pd(0.0);
    #pragma omp for nowait
    for(size_t i=0; i<N/4; i++) {
        count_private++;
        count4 = _mm256_add_pd(count4,_mm256_set1_pd(1.0));
        __m256d t1 = _mm256_loadu_pd(&data[4*i]);
        __m256d t2 = _mm256_div_pd(_mm256_sub_pd(t1, mean4), count4);
        mean4 = _mm256_add_pd(t2, mean4);
    }
    __m256d t1 = _mm256_hadd_pd(mean4,mean4);
    __m128d t2 = _mm256_extractf128_pd(t1,1);
    __m128d t3 = _mm_add_sd(_mm256_castpd256_pd128(t1),t2);
    mean_private = _mm_cvtsd_f64(t3)/4;

    #pragma omp critical
    {
        mean = (count_private*mean_private + count*mean);
        count += count_private;
        mean /= count;
    }   
}
int count2 = 0;
double mean2 = 0;
for(size_t i=4*(N/4); i<N; i++) {
    count2++;
    mean2 += (data[i] - mean2)/count2;
}
mean = (4*(N/4)*mean + count2*mean2)/N;
```

And here is a working example (compile with `-O3 -mavx -fopenmp`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>

double mean_simd(double *data, const int N) {
    double mean = 0.0;
    __m256d mean4 = _mm256_set1_pd(0.0);
    __m256d count4 = _mm256_set1_pd(0.0);
    for(size_t i=0; i<N/4; i++) {
        count4 = _mm256_add_pd(count4,_mm256_set1_pd(1.0));
        __m256d t1 = _mm256_loadu_pd(&data[4*i]);
        __m256d t2 = _mm256_div_pd(_mm256_sub_pd(t1, mean4), count4);
        mean4 = _mm256_add_pd(t2, mean4);           
    }
    __m256d t1 = _mm256_hadd_pd(mean4,mean4);
    __m128d t2 = _mm256_extractf128_pd(t1,1);
    __m128d t3 = _mm_add_sd(_mm256_castpd256_pd128(t1),t2);
    mean = _mm_cvtsd_f64(t3)/4;
    int count = 0;
    double mean2 = 0;
    for(size_t i=4*(N/4); i<N; i++) {
        count++;
        mean2 += (data[i] - mean2)/count;
    }
    mean = (4*(N/4)*mean + count*mean2)/N;
    return mean;
}

double mean_simd_omp(double *data, const int N) {
    double mean = 0.0;
    int count = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel 
    {
        double mean_private = 0.0;
        int count_private = 0;
        __m256d mean4 = _mm256_set1_pd(0.0);
        __m256d count4 = _mm256_set1_pd(0.0);
        #pragma omp for nowait
        for(size_t i=0; i<N/4; i++) {
            count_private++;
            count4 = _mm256_add_pd(count4,_mm256_set1_pd(1.0));
            __m256d t1 = _mm256_loadu_pd(&data[4*i]);
            __m256d t2 = _mm256_div_pd(_mm256_sub_pd(t1, mean4), count4);
            mean4 = _mm256_add_pd(t2, mean4);
        }
        __m256d t1 = _mm256_hadd_pd(mean4,mean4);
        __m128d t2 = _mm256_extractf128_pd(t1,1);
        __m128d t3 = _mm_add_sd(_mm256_castpd256_pd128(t1),t2);
        mean_private = _mm_cvtsd_f64(t3)/4;

        #pragma omp critical
        {
            mean = (count_private*mean_private + count*mean);
            count += count_private;
            mean /= count;
        }   
    }
    int count2 = 0;
    double mean2 = 0;
    for(size_t i=4*(N/4); i<N; i++) {
        count2++;
        mean2 += (data[i] - mean2)/count2;
    }
    mean = (4*(N/4)*mean + count2*mean2)/N;
    return mean;
}


int main() {
    const int N = 1001;
    double data[N];

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) data[i] = 1.0*rand()/RAND_MAX;
    float sum = 0; for(int i=0; i<N; i++) sum+= data[i]; sum/=N;
    printf("mean %f\n", sum);
    printf("mean_simd %f\n", mean_simd(data, N);
    printf("mean_simd_omp %f\n", mean_simd_omp(data, N));
}
```

Comment: That's the right maths for combining two means, but there is a special case of that equation for `mean(n+1)`, i.e. adding one data point, which I'll label `X`.  `mean(n+1) = mean(n) + (X - mean(n)) / (n+1)`.  I would like to use this equation inside your `for` loop, i.e. in place of `tmp += data[i];` as it is a bit more numerically stable than just adding up all the numbers in `data`.

Comment: @chippies, the problem with `mean(n+1) = mean(n) + (X - mean(n)) / (n+1)` is that it's not easily amenable to SIMD. I don't think it will be auto-vectorized. Have you looked at the assembly to see if it's vectorized? I think I could vectorize it manually with intrinsics or a vector class. Maybe you should repost your question with the SSE/AVX tag without the OpenMP stuff. You have already solved the MIMD with OpenMP part.

Comment: @chippies, your problem reminds me of doing the prefix sum (because it has a dependency) with OpenMP and SIMD. I did this. It was not easy but I got it working. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19494114/parallel-prefix-cumulative-sum-with-sse. Post your formula with the AVX tag and see if anyone can figure it out.

Comment: Looking at the disassembly shows that GCC (MinGW x86-64) is actually using the XMM registers and the instructions `vaddsd` and `vdivsd` already.  Since those are the scalar, rather than the packed/SIMD, instructions I'm guessing this isn't really vectorisation but rather some weird optimisation from GCC.  Anyway, I see the same instructions appearing in cases where I try using OpenMP SIMD so OpenMP isn't able to vectorise my code.

Comment: Thanks for your link.  I was hoping OpenMP would have a means for vectorising custom reducers in SIMD, too bad.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @chippies, I rewrote my answer. I think it's much better now. I made sense of your custom reducer. I manged to get the SIMD part working using AVX. I would not be surprised if the SIMD using a single thread is as fast as your OpenMP only code using your four cores (eight threads). In any case I combined the MIMD and SIMD together.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I like your use of `_mm256_hadd_pd` and the final SIMD reduction.  One question though, why do you use `double tmp[4];` and `_mm256_store_pd(tmp,count4);` inside the `for` loop?

Comment: @chippies, haha, that was some left over printf debugging code. I just removed it. Good observation. One thing I did not do was unroll the loop. There is a dependency chain on `mean4`.

Answer (score 0):

The KISS answer: Just calculate the mean outside the loop. Parallelize the following code:

```
double sum = 0.0;
for(size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) sum += data[i];
double mean = sum/N;
```

The sum is easily parallelizeable, but you won't see any effect of SIMD optimization: it is purely memory bound, the CPU will only be waiting for data from memory. If `N` is as small as `1024`, there is even little point in parallelization, the synchronization overhead will eat up all the gains.

Comment: The OP already stated that he want to do it his way because "it is a bit more numerically stable". If N is only 1024 I agree it does not make sense to use MIMD but in that case SIMD still makes sense (and I showed how to do it). But one could assume the OP is doing other calculations between each iteration in which case it might not be memory bound. It does not appear people take the OPs question very seriously. They give up when they see a dependency or just say "calculate the mean the obvious way" (which is what I did in the first iteration of my answer if you look through my edits).

Comment: @Zboson I didn't see the comment about numerical stability. However, from a precision point of view, the sum & divide approach is a tad better because it avoids unnecessary rounding errors due to the divisions. The rounding errors on the additions cannot be avoided. It is true, that the sum approach is a tad more likely to hit infinity. But that requires insanely large numbers and is hardly a concern. It would be a concern if the sum was done in an integer, but not with a `double` accumulator.

Comment: That may be true. In which case the obvious solution is the way to go. But the OP also stated "This gives me a 3.2X speedup on my Core i7 2600k using 8 threads" which tells me that he's running over more than 1024 elements and/or doing something else in between each iteration. There is no way he would get any speed up with OpenMP with only 1024 elements anyway. In fact it would be worse due to the overhead. And even with more elements it would be memory bound so he must be doing something more.

Comment: @Zboson you're right, I was testing on a lot more - 8*1024*1024 elements.  Some extra background to the work is that there are similar equations for variance.  Since all of these equations follow a similar pattern, I wanted to practice on the simple case, the mean, before implementing more complex cases.  Using the equations in that PDF I linked to in my question makes a much bigger difference in the accuracy of higher order statistics.  For an example of how bad it can get [look here](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/09/26/comparing-three-methods-of-computing-standard-deviation/).

Comment: @chippies, yeah I figured this was just the first part of a more complicated calculation you want to do. I hope my solution helps you for the next steps. If the SIMD code is slower than you expect trying unrolling four times. The latency on the add is three so you have to unroll at least three times but you may be dominated by the throughput of the division anyway.