# How to use SSE in case of incremental loops?

Tags: c++, sse

I have a loop like below.

```
for(int i = 0;i < 28;i++)
{
    a[i] = addr + flag;
    flag = flag + b[i];
}
```

Here, I am incrementing the flag for each value of `i`. So in this case, how can the functionality inside the loop can be implemented using SSE.

Comment: What's your end goal, and what are the types of all the variables in use here?

Comment: everything is an integer. for each value of i, am computing a[i] and then incerementing the flag. Is there any way that this can done using SSE

Comment: I think it's not possible as flag depends of previous evaluation.

Comment: is it aleast possibl to load values from different array index values into an sse register instead of loading consecutive array index values?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: It looks to me like you want to do a prefix sum (aka cumulative sum). I doubt any compiler will do this for you using SSE. But it's possible to do with SSE and AVX. I did it with intrinsics for floats https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19494114/parallel-prefix-cumulative-sum-with-sse/19519287#19519287. But you're only looping over 28 elements so I don't know if it's worth doing.

Comment: Yes i was looking for this. Thank u very miuch

Comment: @alkino, it is possible. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is basically a prefix sum (aka cumulative sum). I did this with [SSE and AVX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19494114/parallel-prefix-cumulative-sum-with-sse/19519287#19519287). The following code should do what you want using SSE2.

```
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>

inline __m128i scan_SSE(__m128i x) {
    x = _mm_add_epi32(x, _mm_slli_si128(x, 4)); 
    x = _mm_add_epi32(x, _mm_slli_si128(x, 8));
    return x;
}

void foo(int *a, int *b, const int n, const int addr, int flag) {
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        a[i] = addr + flag;
        flag = flag + b[i];
    }
    printf("flag %d\n", flag);
}

void foo_SSE(int *a, int *b, const int n, const int addr, int flag) { 
    __m128i offset = _mm_setzero_si128();
    __m128i k4 = _mm_set1_epi32(addr+flag-b[0]);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n-3; i+=4) {
        __m128i x = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)&b[i]);
        __m128i out = scan_SSE(x);
        out = _mm_add_epi32(out, offset);
         offset = _mm_shuffle_epi32(out, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 3, 3, 3)); 
        out = _mm_add_epi32(out, k4);
        _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)&a[i], out);

    }    
    for(; i<n; i++) {
        a[i] = addr + flag;
        flag = flag + b[i];
    }
    flag = a[n-1]-addr+b[0];
    printf("flag %d\n", flag);
}

int main() {
    const int n = 24;
    int a[n], b[n];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) a[i] = 1;

    foo(b,a, n, 2,3);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) printf("%d ", b[i]); printf("\n");

    foo_SSE(b,a, n, 2,3);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) printf("%d ", b[i]); printf("\n");
}
```

Output:

```
flag 27
5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
flag 27
5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
```

Comment: Hi.. Thank u so much. I will test tis and inform u... in the mean time, u have any idea how to enable SSE in cygwin

Comment: @vinodc, I just fixed the code. I forgot to output flag. I have not used cygwin in ages. If you compile in 64-bit mode then SSE2 should be enabled by default otherwise with GCC add `-msse2` to your command line options.

Comment: Thank u so much. jus a small clarification. is it possible to load 4 random values into a sse register?

Comment: @vinodc, what do you mean by random values? Do you mean load from memory for which you only allocated but did not define? That's no problem. For floats on older processors you could get denormalized numbers which can be a big hit on performance but it's no problem for new processors and no problem for integers either way.