# how can i understand my code in openMP?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm beginning in openMP and i want parallelize this portion of code :

```
for (i=0 ;i<n ;i++) 
    for (j=1 ;j<n ;j++)  
       A[i][j]+=A[i][j-1];
```

and i find this answer:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j) shared(A, n)
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
  for (j = 1; j < n; ++j)  
    A[i][j] += A[i][j-1];
```

i have some questions:
- why does `i` private and not shared?
- about this answer if i have 4 threads so,each thread have (i = 0; i < n; ++i)and (j = 0; j < n; ++j) iteration? i need your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need help understanding this openMP example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28145951/i-need-help-understanding-this-openmp-example)

Answer (score 1):

1) `i` is private because each thread needs to iterate from `0` to `n` separately; otherwise, if make `i` shared when your threads together will iterate over ONE loop from `0` to `n`.

2) Yes, in this code each thread has it's own copy of `i` and `j` variables and that's why they will operate separately.

3) I am not sure in this example but I can say you must avoid `data dependency` because it cause a problems in making code to work parallel: processors (or `workers`) must do exactly one single job without dependency on another worker's state or result to bring more efficiency. See [SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) and try to find some `vectorization` information. Shortly, vectorization is a technique which helps much in paralellizing code because it implements `SIMD` paradigm. On modern cpu's like `Intel Sandy Bridge` and older architectures using this technique allows you to speed up very much your parallel computing by using `AVX/AVX2` extensions.

Comment: [The for directive splits the for-loop so that each thread in the current team handles a different portion of the loop.](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/) If 3 threads are used, the second thread will have `i` in the range `n/3..2n/3` and `j` in the range `1..n`. So there is no problem regarding data dependency : the `j` loop is not parallel.

Comment: That's why I've said "I am not sure" :) Thanks. But this information is useful to know anyway, I'll keep it in the answer.

Comment: thank you for your interestingly answer, but i don't understand how can i obtain a true result although each thread execute the same code(in case of 4 threads)?

Comment: @francis, the `j` looop is not parallel so the result will be correct, however the dependency of previous iterations on `j` will cause auto-vectorization to fail. [It can be done with SIMD but it's not trivial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19494114/parallel-prefix-cumulative-sum-with-sse).