# Accumulating a running-total (prefix sum) horizontally across an __m256i vector

Tags: c, vectorization, x86-64, intrinsics, avx2

I'm trying to translate some scalar code (`calc_offsets` below) into the AVX2 equivalent. It takes a series of 'counts' and generates a table of offset positions, starting from some provided base value.

My attempt at converting this to AVX2 (`avx2_calc_offsets`), which I think is correct, seems to be about half the speed of the simple array approach. This is part of an effort to translate a larger hot section of (bottlenecked) code into AVX2 instructions and I'm looking to process the offsets further as vectors. I'd like to avoid jumping between AVX2 and scalar code for operations like this.

There's some example and simple benchmarking code provided. I'm getting around 2.15 seconds runtime for the array version and 4.41 seconds for the AVX2 version (on Ryzen Zen v1).

Is there a better approach using AVX2 to make this operation faster? I need to consider older AVX2 CPUs such as Haswell and original Ryzen series.

```c
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef uint32_t u32;
typedef uint64_t u64;

void calc_offsets (const u32 base, const u32 *counts, u32 *offsets)
{
    offsets[0] = base;
    offsets[1] = offsets[0] + counts[0];
    offsets[2] = offsets[1] + counts[1];
    offsets[3] = offsets[2] + counts[2];
    offsets[4] = offsets[3] + counts[3];
    offsets[5] = offsets[4] + counts[4];
    offsets[6] = offsets[5] + counts[5];
    offsets[7] = offsets[6] + counts[6];
}

__m256i avx2_calc_offsets (const u32 base, const __m256i counts)
{
    const __m256i shuff = _mm256_set_epi32 (6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 7);

    __m256i v, t;

    // shift whole vector `v` 4 bytes left and insert `base`
    v = _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32 (counts, shuff);
    v = _mm256_insert_epi32 (v, base, 0);

    // accumulate running total within 128-bit sub-lanes
    v = _mm256_add_epi32 (v, _mm256_slli_si256 (v, 4));
    v = _mm256_add_epi32 (v, _mm256_slli_si256 (v, 8));

    // add highest value in right-hand lane to each value in left
    t = _mm256_set1_epi32 (_mm256_extract_epi32 (v, 3));
    v = _mm256_blend_epi32 (_mm256_add_epi32 (v, t), v, 0x0F);

    return v;
}

void main()
{
    u32 base = 900000000;
    u32 counts[8] = { 5, 50, 500, 5000, 50000, 500000, 5000000, 50000000 };
    u32 offsets[8];

    calc_offsets (base, &counts[0], &offsets[0]);
    
    printf ("calc_offsets: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) printf (" %u", offsets[i]);
    printf ("\n-----\n");

    __m256i v, t;
    
    v = _mm256_loadu_si256 ((__m256i *) &counts[0]);
    t = avx2_calc_offsets (base, v);

    _mm256_storeu_si256 ((__m256i *) &offsets[0], t);
    
    printf ("avx2_calc_offsets: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) printf (" %u", offsets[i]);
    printf ("\n-----\n");

    // --- benchmarking ---

    #define ITERS 1000000000

    // uncomment to benchmark AVX2 version
    // #define AVX2_BENCH

#ifdef AVX2_BENCH
    // benchmark AVX2 version    
    for (u64 i = 0; i < ITERS; i++) {
        v = avx2_calc_offsets (base, v);
    }
    
    _mm256_storeu_si256 ((__m256i *) &offsets[0], v);

#else
    // benchmark array version
    u32 *c = &counts[0];
    u32 *o = &offsets[0];

    for (u64 i = 0; i < ITERS; i++) {
        calc_offsets (base, c, o);
        
        // feedback results to prevent optimizer 'cleverness'
        u32 *tmp = c;
        c = o;
        o = tmp;
    }

#endif 

    printf ("offsets after benchmark: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) printf (" %u", offsets[i]);
    printf ("\n-----\n");
}
```

I'm using `gcc -O2 -mavx2 ...` to build. [Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/6h196WYEv).

Comment: Looks like a [Prefix Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum), aka Inclusive Scan, aka cumulative sum.  Plus some fixed offsets in `counts[8]` which don't really change the dependency pattern.  See [parallel prefix (cumulative) sum with SSE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19494114) for an FP version (including AVX), but as I commented there, integer add latency being lower means the expected speedup is probably less.

Comment: From your question title, I expected it was going to be [Fastest way to do horizontal SSE vector sum (or other reduction)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6996764) where you just want the total.  Probably want to put "running total" or "prefix sum" somewhere in the title.

Comment: @Peter thanks, I'll be happy if I can get it somewhere near the scalar array version even if slightly slower. The main aim is to avoid jumping vector based <-> array-based and back multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

Eliminating the upfront `_mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32` (`vpermd`) seems to make a massive difference here. This is likely because of its large latency (8 cycles on Ryzen?) and the immediate dependency upon it of all subsequent instructions.

Instead of feeding in the base value upfront I'm combining it with during the addition that carries the prefix-sum between 128-bit lanes.

```c
__m256i avx2_calc_offsets_2 (const u32 base, const __m256i counts)
{
    __m256i b, t, v;

    v = counts;

    // accumulate running totals within 128-bit sub-lanes
    v = _mm256_add_epi32 (v, _mm256_slli_si256 (v, 4));
    v = _mm256_add_epi32 (v, _mm256_slli_si256 (v, 8));

    // extract highest value in right-hand lane and combine with base offset
    t = _mm256_set1_epi32 (_mm256_extract_epi32 (v, 3));
    b = _mm256_set1_epi32 (base);
    t = _mm256_blend_epi32 (_mm256_add_epi32 (b, t), b, 0x0F);

    // combine with shifted running totals
    v = _mm256_add_epi32 (_mm256_slli_si256 (v, 4), t);

    return v;
}
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/qMnrTs3jc)

Assembly comparison between the two versions:

```
avx2_calc_offsets:
        vmovdqa ymm1, YMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        vpermd  ymm0, ymm1, ymm0
        vpinsrd xmm1, xmm0, edi, 0
        vinserti128     ymm0, ymm0, xmm1, 0x0
        vpslldq ymm1, ymm0, 4
        vpaddd  ymm0, ymm0, ymm1
        vpslldq ymm1, ymm0, 8
        vpaddd  ymm0, ymm0, ymm1
        vpsrldq xmm1, xmm0, 12
        vpbroadcastd    ymm1, xmm1
        vpaddd  ymm1, ymm1, ymm0
        vpblendd        ymm0, ymm1, ymm0, 15
        ret
avx2_calc_offsets_2:
        vpslldq ymm1, ymm0, 4
        vmovd   xmm2, edi
        vpaddd  ymm1, ymm1, ymm0
        vpbroadcastd    ymm2, xmm2
        vpslldq ymm0, ymm1, 8
        vpaddd  ymm1, ymm1, ymm0
        vpsrldq xmm0, xmm1, 12
        vpslldq ymm1, ymm1, 4
        vpbroadcastd    ymm0, xmm0
        vpaddd  ymm0, ymm2, ymm0
        vpblendd        ymm0, ymm0, ymm2, 15
        vpaddd  ymm0, ymm0, ymm1
        ret
```

Overall the same number of instructions, just less expensive in uops/latency I suppose.

The benchmark using `avx2_calc_offsets_2` now runs in 2.7 seconds, which is around 63% faster than the previous version.

---

**Update 1**: GCC's inlining of `avx2_calc_offsets_2` into the benchmark loop further explains the increased performance. As Peter [predicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69694914/accumulating-a-running-total-prefix-sum-horizontally-across-an-m256i-vector/69696253?noredirect=1#comment123201336_69696253), the `vmovd`/ `vpbroadcastd` instructions corresponding to `_mm256_set1_epi32 (base)` are indeed hoisted out into a single load outside of the loop.

Loop assembly:

```
        ...
        // loop setup
        vmovdqa ymm2, YMMWORD PTR .LC5[rip] // hoisted load of broadcasted base
        vmovdqa ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rbp-176]
        vmovdqa ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rbp-144]
        mov     eax, 1000000000
        jmp     .L10
.L17:   // loop body
        vpslldq ymm1, ymm0, 4
        vpaddd  ymm0, ymm0, ymm1
        vpslldq ymm1, ymm0, 8
        vpaddd  ymm0, ymm0, ymm1
        vpsrldq xmm1, xmm0, 12
        vpslldq ymm0, ymm0, 4
        vpbroadcastd    ymm1, xmm1
        vpaddd  ymm1, ymm1, ymm2
        vpblendd        ymm1, ymm1, ymm2, 15
.L10:   // loop entry
        vpaddd  ymm0, ymm1, ymm0
        sub     rax, 1
        jne     .L17
        ...
.LC5:   // broadcasted `base`
        .long   900000000
        .long   900000000
        .long   900000000
        .long   900000000
        .long   900000000
        .long   900000000
        .long   900000000
        .long   900000000
```

---

**Update 2**:
Focusing on the inlining case and replacing the `_mm256_blend_epi32` / `vpblendd` with an `__m128i` insertion into the high lane of a zeroed `__m256i`, then adding to the final vector yields further performance and code-size improvements ([thanks Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69694914/accumulating-a-running-total-prefix-sum-horizontally-across-an-m256i-vector/69696253?noredirect=1#comment123206859_69696253)).

```c
__m256i avx2_calc_offsets_3 (const u32 base, const __m256i counts)
{
    const __m256i z = _mm256_setzero_si256 ();
    const __m256i b = _mm256_set1_epi32 (base);

    __m256i v, t;
    __m128i lo;

    v = counts;

    // accumulate running totals within 128-bit sub-lanes
    v = _mm256_add_epi32 (v, _mm256_slli_si256 (v, 4));
    v = _mm256_add_epi32 (v, _mm256_slli_si256 (v, 8));

    // capture the max total in low-lane and broadcast into high-lane
    lo = _mm_shuffle_epi32 (_mm256_castsi256_si128 (v), _MM_SHUFFLE (3, 3, 3, 3));
    t  = _mm256_inserti128_si256 (z, lo, 1);
    
    // shift totals, add base and low-lane max 
    v = _mm256_slli_si256 (v, 4);
    v = _mm256_add_epi32 (v, b);
    v = _mm256_add_epi32 (v, t);

    return v;
}
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/zrdb5naMh)

The assembly for the inlined version in the loop now looks like:

```
        // compiled with GCC version 10.3: gcc -O2 -mavx2 ...
        // loop setup
        vmovdqa ymm2, YMMWORD PTR .LC5[rip] // load broadcasted base
        vmovdqa ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rbp-176]
        vmovdqa ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rbp-144]
        mov     eax, 1000000000
        vpxor   xmm3, xmm3, xmm3
        jmp     .L12
.L20:   // loop body
        vpslldq ymm1, ymm0, 4
        vpaddd  ymm0, ymm0, ymm1
        vpslldq ymm1, ymm0, 8
        vpaddd  ymm0, ymm0, ymm1
        vpshufd xmm1, xmm0, 255
        vpslldq ymm0, ymm0, 4
        vinserti128     ymm1, ymm3, xmm1, 0x1
.L12:   // loop entry
        vpaddd  ymm0, ymm0, ymm1
        vpaddd  ymm0, ymm0, ymm2
        sub     rax, 1
        jne     .L20
```

The loop body is down to only 9 vector instructions :).

There's an optimization bug in GCC when using -O3 where an extraneous `vmovdqa ymm0, ymm1` is inserted at the end of the loop body, reducing the benchmark performance by a couple of percent. (At least for GCC versions 11.x, 10.x, and 9.x).

---

**Update 3**: Another slight performance gain. If we add in the low-lane's max total using a SSE/128-bit instruction before the 128-bit insertion, we [shorten the critical path for `v`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69694914/accumulating-a-running-total-prefix-sum-horizontally-across-an-m256i-vector/69696253?noredirect=1#comment123240113_69696253) allowing better use of the shuffle port.

```c
__m256i avx2_calc_offsets_4 (const u32 base, const __m256i counts)
{
    const __m256i b = _mm256_set1_epi32 (base);

    __m256i v, t;
    __m128i lo;

    v = counts;

    // accumulate running totals within 128-bit sub-lanes
    v = _mm256_add_epi32 (v, _mm256_slli_si256 (v, 4));
    v = _mm256_add_epi32 (v, _mm256_slli_si256 (v, 8));

    // capture the max total in low-lane, broadcast into high-lane and add to base
    lo = _mm_shuffle_epi32 (_mm256_castsi256_si128 (v), _MM_SHUFFLE (3, 3, 3, 3));
    lo = _mm_add_epi32 (_mm256_castsi256_si128 (b), lo);

    t = _mm256_inserti128_si256 (b, lo, 1);

    // shift totals, add base and low-lane max 
    v = _mm256_slli_si256 (v, 4);
    v = _mm256_add_epi32 (v, t);

    return v;
}
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/YcMP5ovvT)

```
.L23:   // loop body
        vpslldq ymm1, ymm0, 4
        vpaddd  ymm0, ymm0, ymm1
        vpslldq ymm1, ymm0, 8
        vpaddd  ymm0, ymm0, ymm1
        vpshufd xmm2, xmm0, 255
        vpslldq ymm1, ymm0, 4
.L14:   // loop entry
        vpaddd  xmm0, xmm2, xmm3
        vinserti128     ymm0, ymm4, xmm0, 0x1
        vpaddd  ymm0, ymm1, ymm0
        sub     rax, 1
        jne     .L23
```

This looks fairly optimal to my (non-expert) eye, at least for early AVX2 chips. Benchmark time is brought down to ~2.17 seconds.

Strangely, if I reduce the size of the source code by deleting one of the previous function definitions,  GCC 10 and 11 go a bit haywire and insert 3 (!) additional of `vmovdqa` instructions into the loop ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/dchb9neYs)). The result is a slowdown of ~18% in my benchmark. GCC 9.x seems unaffected. I'm not sure what's going on here but it seems like a pretty nasty bug in GCC's optimizer. I'll try to reduce it and file a bug.

---

The benchmark using `avx2_calc_offsets_3` now runs at effectively the same speed as the scalar version, which is a win in my case since it removes the need to jump to scalar code for performance reasons.

Comment: Yeah, creating instruction-level parallelism by keeping independent work off the latency critical path is definitely a good thing.  On Zen1, worth considering using only 128-bit vectors since each one costs 2 uops anyway.  But for performance on future CPUs it can make sense to keep wider vectors.

Comment: Hopefully when `avx2_calc_offsets_2` inlines into the calling loop, the vmovd / `vpbroadcastd` from `_mm256_set1_epi32 (base)` will get hoisted out of the loop.  (Maybe unlike version 1, where you were doing a `vpinsrd` into the low element of a 128-bit vector.  Note that `_mm256_insert_epi32` isn't a single-instruction intrinsic; there is no `vpinsrd ymm`, it has to be emulated by inserting or blending the original high half.)

Comment: @Peter Indeed it does hoist out `_mm256_set1_epi32 (base)`!

Comment: I notice the loop still has `vpsrldq xmm1, xmm0, 12` / `vpbroadcastd    ymm1, xmm1` with nothing reading the intermediate result.  An alternate way to broadcast the 4th element (#3) of an `__m256i` would be to use a single `vpermd`.  That would be more efficient on Intel CPUs.  (One 3-cycle-latency shuffle uop, same as the vpbroadcastd).  But maybe not on Zen1, where `vpermd ymm` is 3 uops, with 4c throughput so might take up more than a single cycle on the shuffle ports (vs. 3 total shuffle uops: 128-bit byte shift is 1, and xmm->ymm broadcast is another 2, writing both halves of the ymm).

Comment: vpermd might be better on Zen2/3, where `vpermd ymm` is 2 uops, 2c throughput, 3c latency for one of the operands.  (https://uops.info/).  So still not as good as Intel.  Oh, on Zen1, better would be `vpshufd xmm` to broadcast the high 32-bit chunk within the low lane, then just `vinserti128` to itself which is super cheap on Zen1, even cheaper than on CPUs that don't handle 128-bit halves separately.  So `lo = ...(_MM_SHUFFLE(3,3,3,3);` / `_mm256_set_m128i( lo, lo )` or manual cast and insert.  2 total uops on Zen1/2/3, 2c latency on Zen1.  (And insert runs on any vec ALU port on Zen1, IIRC.)

Comment: Replacing `_mm256_set1_epi32 (_mm256_extract_epi32 (v, 3));` with `_mm_shuffle_epi32(...)` / `_mm256_set_m128i(...)` does increase the speed slightly (by around 5%) but annoyingly gcc now inserts  an additional `vmovdqa ymm1, ymm0` at the end of the loop body for no apparent reason. Clang and ICC manage to avoid this. Any idea why and how to get GCC to avoid doing this?

Comment: BTW, clang has a good shuffle optimizer; compiling intrinsics with clang will sometimes optimize into asm with a better idea than your source.  If so, then you can chance your intrinsics to get other compilers to do what clang did.  For example, I just tried your current Godbolt link with clang `-O3 -march=znver1`, and it came up with `vpshufd` / `vinserti128` on its own.  https://godbolt.org/z/dEhY8e3YP

Comment: Really useful to know! You might have missed my comment edit so I'll ask again: Annoyingly GCC now inserts an additional `vmovdqa ymm1, ymm0` at the end of the loop body for no apparent reason. Clang and ICC manage to avoid this. Any idea why and how to get GCC to avoid doing this?

Comment: GCC does sometimes waste an instruction in a loop to set up for one instruction outside a loop.  It's clearly a missed optimization, but I didn't find an existing bug report open for it.  If you want to report it on https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/ with this test case (simplified as much as possible while still reproing, i.e. a [mcve]), it might get fixed at some point.  https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=98981 looks the same, but the cause there is specific to RISC-V integer mov.

Comment: re: last update: you can shorten the critical path through `v` by doing `t = _mm256_add_epi32 (b, t);` in parallel with that final `v = _mm256_slli_si256 (v, 4);` so there's only one `v = add(v, t)` after that.  Hmm, adding to those zero elements makes me wonder if there might be a way to use the insane in-lane [`vpalignr ymm`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/palignr) (`_mm256_alignr_epi8`) at some point to insert the base?  No probably not, you do need it added to the other elements, so adding it to zero in the bottom element is probably the best way to get it there.