# dst[i] eqaul src[i] multiply by dst[i-1] in avx or sse

Tags: simd, sse, avx, avx2, avx512

I have a array with 32 bit float, like this:

```
_m512 float_array = _mm512_setr_ps(a, b, c, d,.....);
```

how can i get:
`_m512 float_array_mul = [a*b, a*b*c, a*b*c*d, ....];`

in other words, Operation like this:
`dst[i+31:i] = src[i+31:i] * dst[i: i-31];`
o

i have no idea about this, Are there some tricks to achieve this?

Comment: Like a prefix sum, but with multiply instead of add.  [parallel prefix (cumulative) sum with SSE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19494114) / [SIMD prefix sum on Intel cpu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10587598) / [Accumulating a running-total (prefix sum) horizontally across an \_\_m256i vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69694914) / etc. And replace `add` with `mul`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I learned these great methods，But there are only 4 float elements in my work scenario，so Any other suggestions for me?

Comment: If you only have 4 float elements, what comes next in the `__m512` vector of 16 floats?  I assumed the `...` continued with more elements.  Did you mean to write `__m128`?  Does the pattern start over and repeat, or you have different sets of 4 elements you want to do in parallel?  IIRC, the first Q&A I linked shows a way to do it within one vector of 4 elements, at least for the case where the first element of the result is `a`, not `a+b` (or in your case `a*b`).  Starting with `a*b`, you get to the end of the prefix scan in 3 vector elements.

Comment: @PeterCordes Adapting the related question is of course not just replacing `add` with `mul`. At some points one needs to insert/replace `0.0` by `1.0` (or blend in values from before performing the multiplication).