# SIMD method to get all consecutive sums of 4 or 8 DWORD integers (prefix-sum within each vector)

Tags: simd, sse, avx, accumulate, prefix-sum

I have 4 or 8 DWORD integer values. Call them vector V.

I want to calculate/accumulate all values, like so:

1. `V[0] + V[1]`
2. `V[0] + V[1] + V[2]`
3. `V[0] + V[1] + V[2] + V[3]`
4. etc, up to `V[0] + ... + V[7]`

I need all of those individual values, not just the scalar sum of the whole register. If there's more output than that, that's fine, and I can just ignore it if so.

Is there an SIMD way to do this that is likely to be more efficient than simply adding them the naive way?

Or is there a mathematical trick/shortcut to this instead or in conjunction with some wide instruction?

Overflow is guaranteed not to occur due to pre-conditions on the incoming values already that end up meaning the sum of all values can never exceed about 2^28-1, so I'm not worried about overflow, and the values are unsigned.

I feel like this is probably something that exists and I just don't know the right terminology for the operation.  (Editor's note: this is a [prefix sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum), cumulative sum, inclusive scan, or "scan".)

Or is this something that is so simple and fast in x86 on modern silicon that the potential costs of explicitly using wide instructions aren't worth it?

The values are already vectorized for other operations, so I've already paid *that* cost, at least.

As for available CPU capabilities, CPU will always be Sapphire Rapids equivalent or later.

Comment: [Accumulating a running-total (prefix sum) horizontally across an \_\_m256i vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69694914) shows some AVX2 code.  I can't think anything AVX-512 has that would be useful.  Within a single vector, you already have a fully general dword shuffle (`vpermd`) and efficient in-lane immediate shuffle (`vpshufd`), and lane-crossing immediate in qword chunks (`vpermq`).  AVX-512's `vpermt2d` is possibly useful for prefix sums over a whole array (across multiple vectors).  Oh maybe `valignd` for an immediate lane-crossing dword-granularity rotate.

Comment: Also related: [parallel prefix (cumulative) sum with SSE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19494114) / [SIMD prefix sum on Intel cpu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10587598) for floating-point over larger arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and the editorial note. I'll have a look at that and wherever it might lead me. :) I'm still pretty green in this area, and this is half for potential actual use and half for my own curiosity/learning.

Comment: From initial investigation, that seems to point me in the right general direction. It's also pretty clear, so far, that it's probably not going to be worth it for this specific operation, as used in the application, vs just accumulating them with plan ol` a + b, in series (since, as used, only 2 registers will be involved), so will probably be internally wicked fast vs messing with SIMD. I also considered 64-bit instructions in sequence or the halves of 128-bit adds plus a plain `+` to get the remaining value. ...or just hoping the compiler will already know a way to make the naive way better.

Comment: Side note: That third link's question wasn't what I'm trying to do, but answers and discussions were still helpful.

Comment: The second link is great, though, and led to this, which explains it really nicely from the horse's mouth and is exactly the operation: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/optimize-scan-operations-explicit-vectorization.html

Comment: The `avx2_calc_offsets_4` implementation in the linked duplicate looks like it compiles to 9 single-uop instructions, only one of them a lane-crossing shuffle.  That's the same as a store + `vmovd` plus seven memory-source `add`s (which can micro-fuse into single-uop with 3/clock throughput), but if you want to store the prefix-sum results you'd need another 7 `mov` instructions (using the destination as the result buffer for storing the initial vector and scalar reloads of it.)

Comment: Ha. I had just begun attempting to do that counting. Still going to trace it through myself, so I can visualize it better. Thanks for your help and insight!

Comment: That Intel whitepaper is about doing prefix scans over larger arrays.  (For 64-bit `double` elements, where FP add has higher latency).  If you're just doing separate prefix-sums across 8-element vectors like you're asking about (ending with `+ v[7]`), latency isn't much of a concern; out-of-order exec can hide that.  The Intel paper uses zero-masked shuffles the way the AVX2 version uses `vpslldq` byte-shifts that shift in zeros.  Interesting trick if you want zeros somewhere other than one end of the vector.

Comment: For counting uops, https://uica.uops.info/ is useful (for small branchless loop bodies).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257239/discussion-between-dodexahedron-and-peter-cordes).

Comment: And BTW, for larger arrays, you want to look at a window larger than 1 vector so you're hiding more latency.  Not have all the work on the next vector depend on highest element of the previous.

Comment: I can definitely understand that. I think the existing code could benefit from a bit of refactoring to enable better and easier use of these concepts. The original is not quite right to make any of it work cleanly, but it is decoupled enough from everything else that I should be able to make it fit nicely into this paradigm without too much work. Plus that'll help avoid an easy XY problem trap. 

Comment: Also for anyone who stumbles upon this, the paper by Guy E. Blelloch from CMU titled "Prefix Sums And Thier Applications" is an interesting read on the underlying concept: https://kilthub.cmu.edu/articles/journal_contribution/Prefix_sums_and_their_applications/6608579/1