# maximum sum of n consecutive elements of array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization

How to find the maximum sum of `n` consecutive numbers of an array? For example if our array is `{2,5,3,4,6}` and `n == 2` then output should be `10` (i.e. `6 + 4`).

I am able to get the logic right for small values of array size and small values of `n`. But when the array size and n are too large like around 10<sup>5</sup>, my code takes a lot of time. Please suggest an optimized approach.

My code snipped:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= n - h; i++) {
  int count = 0;
  for(int k = i; k < i + h; k++) {
    count = count + arr[k];
  }
  if(i == 0) {
    ans[z] = count;
  } else if(i != 0) {
    if(count < ans[z]) {
      ans[z] = count;
    }
  }
  count = 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the error.Its maximum

Comment: My first approach is to traverse the array _once_ from 0 to the upper bound, calculating the sum of the 2 previous items and comparing with the previous sum. How is your code like?

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<=n-h;i++)
  {
   int count=0;
   for(int k=i;k<i+h;k++)
   {
    
    count=count+arr[k];
      }
     
      if(i==0)
      {
       ans[z]=count;
      }
      else if(i!=0)
      {
      
       if(count<ans[z])
       {
        ans[z]=count;
       }
      
      }
      count=0;
  }`  This is my code snippet

Comment: What language is your code snipped? (Looks like C or C++ to me.)

Comment: you may refer to my sample code below, it does not use nested loop to calculate the sum of next sub array

Comment: In you code snipped, what is `n` and `h`? I get the feeling that `h` in your code is the `n` of your description, and `n` of your code is the overall size of the array.

Comment: yes thats right @das-g

Comment: Okay..Just out of curiosity,can this be done using segment tree?

Comment: imagine if your n == 1000, and length of array == 10000.
every new cycle you need to compute sum of 1000 elements.
but the difference between previous sum and current sum is just two components. Think how you can avoid naive summation of 1000 components

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here is my idea: traverse the array from 0 to (array length - N), and determine the sum of next N-item by using the following expression: 
    **sum of next N-item = previous sum - first item in previous sub-array + last item in next sub-array**

Example:

Array = {2,5,3,4,6}

when i = 0, sum = (2 + 5) = 7, max sum = 7

when i = 1, sum = 7 - 2 + 3 = 8, since 8 > 7, so max sum = 8

when i = 2, sum = 8 - 5 + 4 = 7, since 7

when i = 3, sum = 7 - 3 + 6 = 10, since 10 > 8, so max sum = 10

below is the sample code in c#

```cs
static int GetLargestSum(int[] array, int n)
{
    int largestSum = 0;
    int previousSum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= array.Length - n; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                largestSum += array[j];
            }

            previousSum = largestSum;
        }
        else
        {
            int currentSum = previousSum - array[i - 1] + array[i + n - 1];
            if (currentSum > largestSum)
            {
                largestSum = currentSum;
            }
            previousSum = currentSum;
        }
    }

    return largestSum;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be "[...] + **last** item in next sub-array" and consequently in your `else` block `int currentSum = previousSum - array[i - 1] + array[i + n - 1];`?

Comment: @terryfkjc i would require a more optimized approach as this takes a lot of time for large values of n and array-size.

Comment: @swap96 i am not sure how "optimized" you need, have you benchmark in your actual situation? when n is large, and the array is not sorted, the most optimize way should be O(n)

Comment: My array size and 'n' can be upto 10^6.

Comment: I think the solution proposed here has complexity `O(n + (array.Length - n))` == `O(n + array size - n)` == `O(array.Length)`. Thus, the size of `n` shouldn't matter. And `O(array.Length)` **is** optimal: Without parallelization, you can't get better than that, as you have to read every array element at least once.

Comment: @swap96 have you consider to calculate the sum using parallel algorithm? the idea is basically divide the large array into several small array and let multiple cpu to calculate largest sum in sub arrays at same time.

Comment: I would have written it with the intro sum-the-first-n loop outside the sliding-window loop (which would start with `i = 1`).  You want the compiler to restructure it that way anyway.  Also, @das-g is right: you have a bug in your sliding-window.  The element you subtract must be `n+1` away from the one you're adding.  Currently, it's always a distance of 2.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the correction, there is a bug in getting the last element in the next sub array

Comment: re: parallelism: I posted an answer with some ideas about threading, and vectorizing the sum of the first window.  (And vectorizing the whole operation if you want to check 4 consecutive values of `n`.)

Answer (score 2):

```
function maxSubelementsSum(inputArray, count) {
  let maxSum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    maxSum += inputArray[i];
  }
  let tempSum = maxSum;
  for (let i = count; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
    tempSum = tempSum + inputArray[i] - inputArray[i - count];
    maxSum = Math.max(tempSum, maxSum);

  }
  return maxSum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8.

```
int[] numArr = {1,3,5,6,7,12,14,2,3,4}; 
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.stream(numArr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());         
List<Integer> intSumList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<=numArr.length-3; i++)
{
    int intSum = intList.stream().skip(i).limit(3).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();       
    intSumList.add(Integer.valueOf(intSum));
}       
int maxConsecutiveSum = intSumList.stream().reduce(Integer::max).get(); 
System.out.println("Max sum using 3 consecutive integers :"+maxConsecutiveSum);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to go about this. 
So far the most optimized I could think of is in O(n). 
Where you get to traverse the array once.

I used the **sliding window pattern** in solving this

**Here is the main idea behind the solution:**

Get the sum of the first n and store in a variable as temporary max

Set your **max** to the **temporary max**

Loop through the array

At any point in the loop, substract the previous element from the temporary max

And add the element in the next **n** index to the temporary max

Finally compare your main **max** to the **temporary max**

If the max is lesser then set your max to the temporary max

```
function maxSubarraySum(array, num){

    let tempMax = 0
    
    for(let i=0; i<num; i++){
        tempMax += array[i] 
    }
    
    let max = tempMax



    for(i=1; i<array.length - (num-1); i++){

        // Substract the element you are at from the max
        // Add the element at the ith + num
        // compare with the max and reinitialize

        let subs = tempMax - array[i-1]

        tempMax = subs + array[i + num - 1]

        if(max < tempMax){
           max = tempMax
        }
          
    }

    return(max)
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main improvement possible for your technique is a sliding window.  Integer addition has an inverse, subtraction.  This makes it possible to drop elements out of the sum and add new ones, instead of re-computing from scratch.  ([Terryfkjc's answer demonstrates this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31891240/224132)).

As Terryfkjc commented on his answer, there's thread-level parallelism to be had.  You can have different threads check different parts of the array.  If the size of the sliding window is more than half the size of the array, then summing the first `n` should be threaded.  Dividing the work between threads is most tricky when `n` is about half the size of the array.  Much bigger, and it can't slide as far.  Much smaller, and most of the work is just the sliding.

If you're targeting a CPU with vector instructions, we can vectorize the initial sum of the first `w` (window size / width) elements easily enough with SIMD.  For example, using x86 SSE (C/C++ intrinsics):

```c
#include <immintrin.h>
const __m128i *array_vec = (__m128i*)array;
__m128i sums = _mm_loadu_si128(array_vec);  // or start with _mm_setzero_si128()

 // careful to get the loop start/end and increment correct,
 // whether you count by vectors (i++) or by elements (i+=4)
 // You may need a scalar cleanup at the end if window width isn't a multiple of the vector width
for (int i=1; i < width/4 ; i+=1) {
    sums = _mm_add_epi32(sums, _mm_loadu_si128(array_vec+i));
    // if you know the input is aligned, and you're going to compile without AVX/AVX2, then do:
    // sums = _mm_add_epi32(sums, array_vec[i]);
}
__m128i hisums = _mm_bsrli_si128(sums, 8);  // get the high 2 elements into the low 2 elements of a separate vector
sums = _mm_add_epi32(sums, hisums);  // one step of horizontal merging.    
hisums = _mm_bsrli_si128(sums, 4);  // actually, pshufd would be faster for this, since it doesn't need a mov to preserve sums.
sums = _mm_add_epi32(sums, hisums);

int window_sum = _mm_cvtsi128_si32(sums);  // get the low 32bit element
```

I don't think it's possible to vectorize the sliding-window part.  We can't usefully slide 4 separate windows, because every window (vector element) needs to see every array element.

However, if we're interested in 4/8/16 different window sizes (preferably consecutive), then we can do that with vectors.  So, at each loop iteration, we have a vector with the current sliding window sum.  With SSE4.1 `pmaxsd` (for signed 32bit ints), we can do

```c
window_max = _mm_max_epi32(window_max, window_sums);
```

The sliding window operation becomes: add the `{ a[i], a[i+1], a[i+2], a[i+3] }`, while removing the same array element from all 4 vector elements.  (Alternatively, broadcast the element to add, and subtract a vector of different elements.)

```c
__m128i add_elements = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&array[i]);  // load i, i+1, etc.
__m128i sub_element = _mm_cvtsi32_si128(array[i-width-1]);
  sub_element = _mm_shuffle_epi32(sub_element, 0); // broadcast the low element of the vector to the other positions.
  // AVX2: use _mm_broadcastd_epi32
  // AVX512 has a broadcast mode for memory references that can be used with most instructions.  IDK how to use it with intrinsics.
__m128i diff = _mm_sub_epi32(add_elements, sub_element);
window_sums = _mm_add_epi32(window_sums, diff);
```

Getting the loop start/end conditions right, and accounting for the last few elements correctly, is always the challenge with vectors.

See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for more about how to use vectors on x86.

Comment: Perhaps it is possible to compute prefix sums with SSE/AVX, and then we can easily compute *max(S[i+n] - S[i])* in vectorized way.

Comment: @stgatilov.  Prefix sums would be useful if you could generate them on the fly as your array was being written, or if you wanted several different window sizes.  Otherwise I think a 2-pass algo would be doomed to failure by memory bandwidth unless it fit in L2 (256k).  And also, I don't think prefix sums can vectorize, because there's no independence between elements.  Every `p[i]` needs to see `a[i-i]`, `a[i-2]`, etc. so you need a horizontal operation at every step.  I think it's the same problem as trying to vectorize the sliding window directly.

Comment: @stgatilov: Turns out you can SIMD a prefix sum, but it takes a lot of shuffling.  Maybe only worth it for floats, where add latency is higher.    See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587598/simd-prefix-sum-on-intel-cpu.  You can also parallelize prefix sums with threads, but the necessary access pattern doesn't look good for SIMD vectors.  http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html.

Answer (score 0):

Using sliding window, where window size of 2

```
arr = [2,5,3,4,6];

sum = 0;
temp_sum = 0;

const add = (a,b) => a+b;

for(let i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++){
  console.log(i, i+2,arr.slice(i,i+2));
  temp_sum = add.apply(null, arr.slice(i,i+2));
  if(sum < temp_sum){
    sum = temp_sum;
  }
}

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a short fast solution :

```
    s = 0
    arrayMaxConsecutiveSum = (a, k) =>
    Math.max(...
        a.map(x => s += x - ~~a[~--k])
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def maxSubarraySum(array, noOfelements):
    start = 0
    sum = 0
    nextElement = 1
    maxSum = []
    while noOfelements < len(array)+1:
        for i in range(start, noOfelements):
            sum += array[i]
        maxSum.append(sum)
        sum = 0
        start = nextElement
        nextElement += 1
        noOfelements += 1
    return max(maxSum) if maxSum else None


def sub(array,ele):
    maxSum = []
    end = ele
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if end <= len(array):
            maxSum.append(sum(array[i:end]))
            end += 1
    return max(maxSum) if maxSum else None

def sub1(array,ele):
    tot = [sum(array[i:ele+i]) for i in range(len(array)) if ele+i <= 
    len(array)]
    return max(tot) if tot else None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(maxSubarraySum([-1, -2, -5, -3, -8, -1, -5], 4) == -11)
    print(maxSubarraySum([1, -2, 5, 3, -8, 1, 5], 4) == 7)
    print(maxSubarraySum([1, 2, 5, 3, 8, 1, 5], 4) == 18)
    print(maxSubarraySum([1, 2, 5, 3, 8, 1, 5], 2) == 11)
    print(maxSubarraySum([], 4) == None)
```

complexity = O(n*n)
This will work for all given arrays including negative numbers.

Added one more with O(n) - Sub function

one more using list comprehension. - Sub1 function

Answer (score 0):

**Using sliding window technique**

```
int curr_sum = 0, max_sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
     curr_sum += v[i];
}
max_sum = curr_sum;
for(int i = k; i < v.size(); i++)
{
    curr_sum += v[i] - v[i-k];
    max_sum = max(max_sum, curr_sum);
}

cout<<max_sum;
```

Time Complexity: θ(n)

Auxiliary Space: O(1)

**Explanation:**
[ 1 8 30 -5 20 7] and n = 3

from 0 to n-1 (0 to 2) curr_sum = 1+8+30 = 39

max_sum = 39

fromr n to v.size()-1 (3 to 5)

curr_sum = prev sum + new element - prev window first element

curr_sum = 39 +(-5)-1 = 33

max_sum = max(39,33) = 39

curr_sum = 33 + 20 - 8 = 45

max_sum = max(39,45) = 45

curr_sum = 45 + 7 - 30 = 22

max_sum = max(45,22) = **45**

Answer (score 0):

let's use the sliding window approach, which performs the sum of sub-array of size n, then loop through the array till len(arr) - n and perform a simple comparison, you can consider this solution:

```
def max_sum(arr, window):
    n = len(arr)

    if (n <= window):
        return -1

    window_sum = sum([arr[i] for i in range(window)])
    maxSum = window_sum

    for i in range(n - window):
        window_sum = window_sum - arr[i] + arr[i + window]
        maxSum = max(window_sum, maxSum)
    
    return maxSum
```

Answer (score -1):

Simplest of them all

```
A=list(map(int,input().split(" ")))
n=len(A)
max=0
for i in range(n-1):
    if(A[i]+A[i+1]>max):
        max=A[i]+A[i+1]
print(max)
```

Answer (score -1):

**Simply we can iterate the array and find the sum of two consecutive numbers**

```
let array = [2,5,3,4,6];
let sum=0;
let maxNumber = 0;
for(let i=0; i<array.length;i++){
    sum = array[i] + array[i+1];
    if(sum >= maxNumber){
        maxNumber = sum;
    }
    
}
console.log("max of two digit :", maxNumber);
```

Answer (score -2):

The first thing I would suggest you is sorting the array using mergesort, this has a complexity time of O(n log(n)) then you only have to find the first n consecutive numbers iterating the array from the higher number to the lower one keeping the sum of the current consecutive numbers and this will take a complexity time of O(n). Greetings

Comment: if we sort the array before calculate the sum, we will get 11 instead of 10 in {2,5,3,4,6}

Comment: if you sort the array then order will not be conserved. and choosing first n elements will not guarantee that it is a contiguous subarray of given array.