# Determining how many clock cycles a codeblock need

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, cpu, performance-testing

Is there a tool or method, which tells me how much clockcycles a codeblock uses?
debugging and counting by hand is a a pain for huger codeblocks.

Comment: On a modern processor (e.g. modern x86), this isn't normally a meaningful/useful statistic (due to out-of-order execution, memory stalls, instruction caching, branch prediction, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On x86, [Intel's IACA (Intel Architecture Code Analyzer](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-architecture-code-analyzer) is the only static analyzer I know of.  It assume zero cache misses, and various other simplifications, but is somewhat useful.

I think it also assumes all but the last branch are not-taken, so it's probably not useful for a loop body with taken branches.

IACA also has some mistakes in its data, e.g. it thinks `shld` is slow on Sandybridge.  It does know about some non-obvious things, like the fact that [SnB-family CPUs can't micro-fuse 2-register addressing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046634/micro-fusion-and-addressing-modes/31027695#31027695).

It's essentially been abandoned since the update for Haswell.  Skylake can run some instructions on more execution ports than Haswell (see [Agner Fog's instruction tables](http://agner.org/optimize)), but the pipeline is similar enough that the results should be fairly useful.  See also other links at the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki, including Intel's optimization manuals, to help you make sense of the output.

---

I like to use this `iaca.sh` wrapper script to make `-64` the default (which I can override with `-32`).  I forget how much of this I wrote (maybe just the `if (($# >= 1))` bit at the end) and where the LD_LIBRARY_PATH part came from.

`iaca.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
myname=$(realpath "$0")
mypath=$(dirname "$myname")
ld_lib="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
app_loc="../lib"

if [ "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" = "" ]
then
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$mypath/$app_loc"
else
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$mypath/$app_loc:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
fi

if (($# >= 1));then
    exec "$mypath/iaca" -64 "$@"
else
    exec "$mypath/iaca"  # there is no -help, just run with no args for help output
fi
```

---

example:  in-place prefix sums, from [SIMD prefix sum on Intel cpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587598/simd-prefix-sum-on-intel-cpu/10589306#10589306):

```
#include <immintrin.h>

#ifdef IACA_MARKS_OFF
  #define IACA_START
  #define IACA_END
#else
  #include <iacaMarks.h>
#endif

// In-place rewrite an array of values into an array of prefix sums.
// This makes the code simpler, and minimizes cache effects.
int prefix_sum_sse(int data[], int n)
{

//    const int elemsz = sizeof(data[0]);
#define elemsz sizeof(data[0])   // clang-3.5 doesn't allow const int foo = ... as an imm8 arg to intrinsics

    __m128i *datavec = (__m128i*)data;
    const int vec_elems = sizeof(*datavec)/elemsz;
    // to use this for int8/16_t, you still need to change the add_epi32, and the shuffle

    const __m128i *endp = (__m128i*) (data + n - 2*vec_elems);  // pointer to last full vector we can load
    __m128i carry = _mm_setzero_si128();
    for(; datavec <= endp ; datavec += 2) {
        IACA_START
        __m128i x0 = _mm_load_si128(datavec + 0);
        __m128i x1 = _mm_load_si128(datavec + 1); // unroll / pipeline by 1
//      __m128i x2 = _mm_load_si128(datavec + 2);
//      __m128i x3;

        x0 = _mm_add_epi32(x0, _mm_slli_si128(x0, elemsz));
        x1 = _mm_add_epi32(x1, _mm_slli_si128(x1, elemsz));

        x0 = _mm_add_epi32(x0, _mm_slli_si128(x0, 2*elemsz));
        x1 = _mm_add_epi32(x1, _mm_slli_si128(x1, 2*elemsz));

        // more shifting if vec_elems is larger

        x0 = _mm_add_epi32(x0, carry);  // this has to go after the byte-shifts, to avoid double-counting the carry.
        _mm_store_si128(datavec +0, x0); // store first to allow destructive shuffle (e.g. non-avx shufps for FP or pshufb for narrow integers)

        x1 = _mm_add_epi32(_mm_shuffle_epi32(x0, _MM_SHUFFLE(3,3,3,3)), x1);
        _mm_store_si128(datavec +1, x1);

        carry = _mm_shuffle_epi32(x1, _MM_SHUFFLE(3,3,3,3)); // broadcast the high element for next vector
    }
    // FIXME: scalar loop to handle the last few elements
    IACA_END
    return data[n-1];
    #undef elemsz
}
```

---

```
$ gcc -I/opt/iaca-2.1/include -Wall -O3 -c prefix-sum.c -march=nehalem -mtune=haswell
$ iaca.sh prefix-sum.o
Intel(R) Architecture Code Analyzer Version - 2.1
Analyzed File - prefix-sum.o
Binary Format - 64Bit
Architecture  - HSW
Analysis Type - Throughput

Throughput Analysis Report
--------------------------
Block Throughput: 6.40 Cycles       Throughput Bottleneck: Port5

Port Binding In Cycles Per Iteration:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Port  |  0   -  DV  |  1   |  2   -  D   |  3   -  D   |  4   |  5   |  6   |  7   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cycles | 1.0    0.0  | 5.7  | 1.4    1.0  | 1.4    1.0  | 2.0  | 6.3  | 1.0  | 1.3  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

N - port number or number of cycles resource conflict caused delay, DV - Divider pipe (on port 0)
D - Data fetch pipe (on ports 2 and 3), CP - on a critical path
F - Macro Fusion with the previous instruction occurred
* - instruction micro-ops not bound to a port
^ - Micro Fusion happened
# - ESP Tracking sync uop was issued
@ - SSE instruction followed an AVX256 instruction, dozens of cycles penalty is expected
! - instruction not supported, was not accounted in Analysis

| Num Of |                    Ports pressure in cycles                     |    |
|  Uops  |  0  - DV  |  1  |  2  -  D  |  3  -  D  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1    |           |     | 1.0   1.0 |           |     |     |     |     |    | movdqa xmm3, xmmword ptr [rax]
|   1    | 1.0       |     |           |           |     |     |     |     |    | add rax, 0x20
|   1    |           |     |           | 1.0   1.0 |     |     |     |     |    | movdqa xmm0, xmmword ptr [rax-0x10]
|   0*   |           |     |           |           |     |     |     |     |    | movdqa xmm1, xmm3
|   1    |           |     |           |           |     | 1.0 |     |     | CP | pslldq xmm1, 0x4
|   1    |           | 1.0 |           |           |     |     |     |     |    | paddd xmm1, xmm3
|   0*   |           |     |           |           |     |     |     |     |    | movdqa xmm3, xmm0
|   1    |           |     |           |           |     | 1.0 |     |     | CP | pslldq xmm3, 0x4
|   0*   |           |     |           |           |     |     |     |     |    | movdqa xmm4, xmm1
|   1    |           | 1.0 |           |           |     |     |     |     |    | paddd xmm3, xmm0
|   1    |           |     |           |           |     | 1.0 |     |     | CP | pslldq xmm4, 0x8
|   0*   |           |     |           |           |     |     |     |     |    | movdqa xmm0, xmm3
|   1    |           | 1.0 |           |           |     |     |     |     |    | paddd xmm1, xmm4
|   1    |           |     |           |           |     | 1.0 |     |     | CP | pslldq xmm0, 0x8
|   1    |           | 1.0 |           |           |     |     |     |     |    | paddd xmm1, xmm2
|   1    |           | 0.8 |           |           |     | 0.2 |     |     | CP | paddd xmm0, xmm3
|   2^   |           |     |           |           | 1.0 |     |     | 1.0 |    | movaps xmmword ptr [rax-0x20], xmm1
|   1    |           |     |           |           |     | 1.0 |     |     | CP | pshufd xmm1, xmm1, 0xff
|   1    |           | 0.9 |           |           |     | 0.1 |     |     | CP | paddd xmm0, xmm1
|   2^   |           |     | 0.3       | 0.3       | 1.0 |     |     | 0.3 |    | movaps xmmword ptr [rax-0x10], xmm0
|   1    |           |     |           |           |     | 1.0 |     |     | CP | pshufd xmm1, xmm0, 0xff
|   0*   |           |     |           |           |     |     |     |     |    | movdqa xmm2, xmm1
|   1    |           |     |           |           |     |     | 1.0 |     |    | cmp rdx, rax
|   0F   |           |     |           |           |     |     |     |     |    | jnb 0xffffffffffffff94
Total Num Of Uops: 20
```

Note that the total uop count is *not* fused-domain uops that matter for the frontend, ROB, and 4-wide issue/retire width.  It counts unfused-domain uops, which matter for the execution units (and scheduler).  It's kind of silly though, because in the unfused domain it mostly matters which port a uop needs, not how many there are.

This isn't the best example because it's trivially bottlenecked on the shuffle port in Haswell.  It does show how IACA displays mov-elimination, micro-fused stores, and macro-fused compare-and-branch, though.

The distribution of uops between ports when there's a choice is fairly arbitrary.  Don't expect it to match what real hardware does.  I don't think IACA models the ROB/scheduler at all, really.  This and other limitations have been discussed in previous SO questions.  Try searching on IACA, since it's a fairly unique string.