# Any chance to accelerate recurrent code with SIMD?

Tags: c++, performance, vectorization, simd, avx2

Consider the following code where `a` is a parameter array of `float` and `s` is an initially uninitialized result array of `float`:

```
s[n - 1] = mu * a[n - 1];
for (int j = n - 2; j >= 0; j--)
    s[j] = mu * (a[j] + s[j + 1]);
return s;
```

Is there any chance to improve the performance of such recurrent code with SIMD (AVX2)?

EDIT: I figured out later that this formula/algorithm is called "discounted sum", but couldn't find its parallel version on the internet.

Comment: Are you sure your compiler doesn't already use SIMD instructions in an optimized build?

Comment: @DanielLangr: huh what?  `mulss` is *scalar* single.  I don't see any SIMD instructions, the only `ps` instruction is a register copy (which of course uses `movaps`, not a `movss` merge with false dependencies).  ICC can't even optimize the sign-extension from int -> pointer width out of the loop, because of your `i <= n-2` between signed `int i` and `size_t` `n-2`.  Although signed-overflow UB should have allowed that.

Answer (score 6):

Related: [Is it possible to use SIMD on a serial dependency in a calculation, like an exponential moving average filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53804648/is-it-possible-to-use-simd-on-a-serial-dependency-in-a-calculation-like-an-expo/53805437#53805437) - If there's a closed-form formula for n steps ahead, you can use that to sidestep serial dependencies.  But I don't think that's the case here.

This looks like a prefix sum type of serial dependency, on top of a vertical add with `a[j]`.  There are ways to accelerate that, getting a speedup of something like
`O( SIMD_width / log(SIMD_width) )`.

- [SIMD prefix sum on Intel cpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587598/simd-prefix-sum-on-intel-cpu)
- [parallel prefix (cumulative) sum with SSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19494114/parallel-prefix-cumulative-sum-with-sse)

Comment: Still, I'm not getting how to extend the prefix sum algorithm to discounting by `mu`.

Comment: @SergeRogatch: I haven't thought that through.  You might need to multiply by a vector like `set(1, mu, mu*mu, mu*mu*mu)` at some point.  Or multiply by `set1(mu)` after each shuffle step, so you end up with mu cubed for `j+3` element by the time it gets down to the bottom of the vector?  I'm probably not going to end up getting back to this, but maybe that's a good starting point for you or someone else that wants to take a crack at answering this.

Answer (score 2):

It sometimes helps to write expressions as matrix-vector products. Assuming you already know `sₖ₊₈` you can calculate `sₖ` to `sₖ₊₇` from `aₖ` to `aₖ₊₇` using

```
 [ µ  µ² µ³ µ⁴ µ⁵ µ⁶ µ⁷ µ⁸]   [aₖ₊₀     ]
 [ 0  µ  µ² µ³ µ⁴ µ⁵ µ⁶ µ⁷]   [aₖ₊₁     ]
 [ 0  0  µ  µ² µ³ µ⁴ µ⁵ µ⁶]   [aₖ₊₂     ]
 [ 0  0  0  µ  µ² µ³ µ⁴ µ⁵]   [aₖ₊₃     ]
 [ 0  0  0  0  µ  µ² µ³ µ⁴] * [aₖ₊₄     ]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  µ  µ² µ³]   [aₖ₊₅     ]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  µ  µ²]   [aₖ₊₆     ]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  µ ]   [aₖ₊₇+sₖ₊₈]
```

Since the `sₖ₊₈` will likely have some latency when this is calculated, it makes sense to move it out of the product. This can be calculated with one broadcast and one fused-multiple-add:

```
 [ µ  µ² µ³ µ⁴ µ⁵ µ⁶ µ⁷ µ⁸]   [aₖ₊₀]   [ µ⁸]
 [ 0  µ  µ² µ³ µ⁴ µ⁵ µ⁶ µ⁷]   [aₖ₊₁]   [ µ⁷]
 [ 0  0  µ  µ² µ³ µ⁴ µ⁵ µ⁶]   [aₖ₊₂]   [ µ⁶]
 [ 0  0  0  µ  µ² µ³ µ⁴ µ⁵]   [aₖ₊₃]   [ µ⁵]
 [ 0  0  0  0  µ  µ² µ³ µ⁴] * [aₖ₊₄] + [ µ⁴] * sₖ₊₈
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  µ  µ² µ³]   [aₖ₊₅]   [ µ³]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  µ  µ²]   [aₖ₊₆]   [ µ²]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  µ ]   [aₖ₊₇]   [ µ ]
```

And the first matrix can be decomposed into three matrices which can be calculated using one shuffle and one FMA each:

```
 [ 1  0  0  0  µ⁴ 0  0  0 ]   [ 1  0  µ² 0  0  0  0  0 ]   [ µ  µ² 0  0  0  0  0  0 ]   [aₖ₊₀]   [ µ⁸]
 [ 0  1  0  0  µ³ 0  0  0 ]   [ 0  1  µ  0  0  0  0  0 ]   [ 0  µ  0  0  0  0  0  0 ]   [aₖ₊₁]   [ µ⁷]
 [ 0  0  1  0  µ² 0  0  0 ]   [ 0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0 ]   [ 0  0  µ  µ² 0  0  0  0 ]   [aₖ₊₂]   [ µ⁶]
 [ 0  0  0  1  µ  0  0  0 ]   [ 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0 ]   [ 0  0  0  µ  0  0  0  0 ]   [aₖ₊₃]   [ µ⁵]
 [ 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0 ] * [ 0  0  0  0  1  0  µ² 0 ] * [ 0  0  0  0  µ  µ² 0  0 ] * [aₖ₊₄] + [ µ⁴] * sₖ₊₈
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0 ]   [ 0  0  0  0  0  1  µ  0 ]   [ 0  0  0  0  0  µ  0  0 ]   [aₖ₊₅]   [ µ³]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0 ]   [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0 ]   [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  µ  µ²]   [aₖ₊₆]   [ µ²]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1 ]   [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1 ]   [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  µ ]   [aₖ₊₇]   [ µ ]
```

The right-most matrix-vector-product is actually one multiplication more.

Overall, for 8 elements you need 4FMAs, one multiplication and 4 shuffles/broadcasts (`$$$$` means anything (finite) can be here -- alternatively, if these are guaranteed to be 0, the `µ` vectors could be partially shared. All vectors are notated least-significant-first, all multiplications are element-wise):

```
bₖₖ₊₇  = [aₖ₊₀, aₖ₊₁, aₖ₊₂, aₖ₊₃, aₖ₊₄, aₖ₊₅, aₖ₊₆, aₖ₊₇] * [µ  µ  µ  µ  µ  µ  µ  µ ]     vmulps
bₖₖ₊₇ += [aₖ₊₁, $$$$, aₖ₊₃, $$$$, aₖ₊₅, $$$$, aₖ₊₆, $$$$] * [µ² 0  µ² 0  µ² 0  µ² 0 ]     vshufps (or vpsrlq) + vfmadd 

cₖₖ₊₇  =  bₖₖ₊₇ 
cₖₖ₊₇ += [bₖ₊₂, bₖ₊₂, $$$$, $$$$, bₖ₊₆, bₖ₊₆, $$$$, $$$$] * [µ² µ  0  0  µ² µ  0  0 ]     vshufps + vfmadd

dₖₖ₊₇  =  cₖₖ₊₇ 
dₖₖ₊₇ += [cₖ₊₄, cₖ₊₄, cₖ₊₄, cₖ₊₄, $$$$, $$$$, $$$$, $$$$] * [µ⁴ µ³ µ² µ  0  0  0  0 ]     vpermps + vfmadd

sₖₖ₊₇ = dₖₖ₊₇ 
       + [sₖ₊₈, sₖ₊₈, sₖ₊₈, sₖ₊₈, sₖ₊₈, sₖ₊₈, sₖ₊₈, sₖ₊₈] * [µ⁸ µ⁷ µ⁶ µ⁵ µ⁴ µ³ µ² µ ]     vbroadcastss + vfmadd
```

If I analyzed it correctly, the calculation of multiple `dₖ` can interleave which would cancel out latencies. And the only hot-path would be the final `vbroadcastss + vfmadd` to calculate `sₖₖ₊₇` from `dₖₖ₊₇` and `sₖ₊₈`. It *could* be worthwhile to calculate blocks of 16 `sₖ` and `fmadd` `µⁱ * sₖ₊₁₆` to that.
Also, the FMAs to calculate `dₖ` only use half of the elements. With some sophisticated swizzling one could calculate two blocks with the same number of FMAs (I assume this is not worth the effort -- but feel free to try that out).

For comparison: A pure scalar implementation requires 8 additions and 8 multiplications for 8 elements, and every operation depends on the previous result.

---

N.B. You could save one multiplication, if instead of your formula you calculated:

```
sₖ = aₖ₊₁ + µ*sₖ₊₁
```

also, in a scalar version you would have Fused-Multiple-Adds, instead of first adding and multiplying afterwards. The result would only differ by a factor of `µ`.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean vectorization then no, not directly. Since the calculation uses the value of the previous iteration to calculate the next it’s not trivially vectorized.

Also unaligned use of `s` may cause issues. Looping from the end maybe also.

If you mean just instructions in the SIMD sets, then maybe they could be used but not necessarily bringing huge benefits and the compilers often know how to do this anyway.