# Is A[i]+=A[i+1] kind of data dependency in a loop ? Can it be vectorized?

Tags: c, vectorization, simd, auto-vectorization

As far as I know, a loop that has serial data dependencies such as `A[i] += A[i-1]` can't be vectorized.

But I'm not sure that `A[i] += A[i+1]` is a raw data dependency or not and if this loop can be vectorized?

```
for(i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    A[i] += A[i + 1];
}
```

Comment: It can be vectorized according to Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_vectorization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop counter is increasing (`i++`) so you're looking *ahead* with `A[i+1]`, not behind.  **That means you're just reading the same original-input elements twice, not re-reading any recent outputs.**  Thus there's no serial dependency.

Just try it with a compiler and see vector loads / stores instead of scalar.  (Easy to tell the difference with integer instead of FP, when compiling for x86).  e.g. on https://godbolt.org/ with gcc or clang `-O3`

On a machine with efficient unaligned loads (like modern x86) your compiler will probably just do loads of `A[ i +0..3]` and `A[ i+1 + 0..3 ]`, but the other option is shuffling to create the offset vector, e.g. using x86 SSSE3 `palignr` which was designed for that and was really helpful on Core 2 (which did *not* have efficient SIMD unaligned loads).

**GCC and clang do both vectorize it for x86-64 with SSE2** (which is baseline for x86-64)
**https://godbolt.org/z/HdNsvC** - 
GCC9.1 for x86-64 (with the default `-mtune=generic` and only SSE2 available) chooses to do 2x load + add + store.  clang8.0 chooses to unroll (as usual) and load from `A[i+1 +4*unroll + 0..3]` and use `shufps` to create the `A[i + 0..3]` vectors.  The middle-end optimizer probably uses a recipe that was good with `palignr`, but then has to emulate it once it gets to code-gen and only has SSE2, not SSSE3.  Also it's likely that input pointers will be 16-byte aligned, so loading vectors from `16*n + 4` bytes relative to that is unfortunate.  Except it will bottleneck on shuffle throughput on recent Intel CPUs anyway.

Clang with AVX1 but not AVX2 (e.g. `-march=sandybridge`) makes a hilarious mess: using 256-bit FP shuffles in multiple steps to emulate 256-bit `palignr`, but then unpacking to 128-bit vectors for integer SIMD `vpaddd` (packed 32-bit add), then `vinsertf128` back to 256-bit for 256-bit stores.  SnB doesn't even have 256-bit load/store units so those uops take 2 cycles to run, and have much larger than usual penalties for misaligned data.

---

**`A[i] += A[i-1]` is harder to vectorize**, but with efficient shuffles there are speedups to be had, especially with floating point where the latency of the serial dependency hurts much more.

- [SIMD prefix sum on Intel cpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587598/simd-prefix-sum-on-intel-cpu)
- [parallel prefix (cumulative) sum with SSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19494114/parallel-prefix-cumulative-sum-with-sse)

Or in general if there's a closed-form formula for striding `n` steps ahead, you can run that in parallel in the elements of a SIMD vector, like in [Is it possible to use SIMD on a serial dependency in a calculation, like an exponential moving average filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53804648/is-it-possible-to-use-simd-on-a-serial-dependency-in-a-calculation-like-an-expo)

Comment: Side question. You seem to know a bit about optimization, is there a book or two you'd recommend?

Comment: @tay10r: Agner Fog's optimization guides are excellent.  (https://agner.org/optimize/).  Once you know what the machine can do efficiently, writing C or C++ that compiles efficiently is something you can aim for, and check by looking at the compiler's asm output.  See also other links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Comment: Your answer has really helped me. Thank you so much, Sir.

Answer (score 0):

This loop below can be vectorized.

```
for(i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    A[i] += A[i + 1];
}
```

We can write the operation in another way:

```
Vector A = ...;           // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Vector B = ShiftLeft(A);  // 2, 3, 4, 5, 0 you dont create new array, no performance loss
Vector C = A + B;         // 3, 5, 7, 9, 5
```

It is not hard to vectorize so..
As Peter Cordes, what?? Hi Peter ^^. As Peter said `A[i] += A[i - 1];` is harder and would be a different scenario.