# what is the dependency between these variables?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-architecture

given this piece of asm code:

```
(Line 1) .L6:
(Line 2) movsd -8(%rdx,%rax,8), %xmm0 
(Line 3) .L2:
(Line 4) addsd (%rcx,%rax,8), %xmm0
(Line 5) movsd %xmm0, (%rdx,%rax,8)
(Line 6) addq $1, %rax
(Line 7) cmpq %rax, %r8
(Line 8) jne .L6
```

1 ) What is the dependency between xmm0 in Line 2 and Line 4? Is my guess of it being *Read after Write* correct?

2 ) What about the dependency between line 4 and 5? In line 4, it does seem like xmm0 is being both read and written (in that order). And in line 5 it's being read and then copied into the location (%rdx,%rax,8). So is it *Read after Read*? Or *Read After Write*?

I'm confused as there are more than 2 (read,write,read) operations happening so not sure which ones would be considered when looking at data dependencies.

this is the c code:

```
void randomgenericfunction(double a[], double p[], long n)
{
     long i;
     p[0] = a[0];
     for (i=1; i<n; i++) {
         p[i] = p[i-1] + a[i];
     }
     return;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Line 2 only writes `xmm0`, line 4 reads and then writes it, line 5 only reads it.  So 2 to 4 and 4 to 5 are both read after write.

I suppose you could argue that 4 to 5 is also read after read, but that's not really a dependency since two reads don't have any effect on each other.  If line 4 were changed to only read xmm0, and not write it, then it would be perfectly fine for a compiler or CPU from reordering it with line 5.  So that second "dependency" isn't worth mentioning.

Comment: yep I was mistaken in thinking that the dependency would include the two reads. thanks for clearing that up! :)

Comment: Read-after-read isn't any kind of hazard or dependency at all.  To be hazardous, there needs to be at least one write.  (Just like C non-atomic variables, concurrent unsynchronized reads are safe.)

Answer (score 2):

`addsd` reads and writes its destination operand, so the read side of that is a RAW relative to the earlier load.

The write side would be a WAW, but the write can't happen until after the read (because addsd can't produce a value until after both its inputs are ready) so you wouldn't normally call that a separate hazard.  Any way of handling the RAW dependency in any normal / standard way would already avoid / take care of the WAW hazard.

e.g. register renaming (Tomasulo) would keep track of the fact that `addsd` is reading the load result, and later reads of XMM0 are reading the `addsd` result, until the next write creates another version of the register.  (A lot like [SSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) Static Single Assignment).  Or in any kind of pipeline, there won't be a value to write back until after the load value has been safely read.

I guess you could imagine a case like `mulsd %xmm0, %xmm5` between the load and the addsd, and you need it to read the load result, not the `addsd` result, even if XMM5 was the result of a cache-miss load and isn't available until long after XMM0, so the `addsd` could have executed before an earlier read of XMM0.  Obviously an in-order pipeline would have stalled waiting for XMM5 to be ready before execution could reach the `addsd` that reads+writes XMM0, and a register-renaming pipeline (like all modern x86) would handle it via renaming.

---

> dependency between line 4 and 5?  So is it Read after Read?

That's not hazardous.  It's always safe to have multiple concurrent readers of the same register or value.  **There's no such thing as a RAR hazard**; at least one write must be involved for things to get tricky.

Yes, storing the `addsd` result is a RAW hazard (true dependency).  The store-data uop needs to wait for the result from that FP add.

(Fun fact: on Intel CPUs, the store-address uop runs on a separate execution port, independently of the store data, writing the address into the store-buffer entry that was allocated during issue/alloc/rename when the uops of this instruction entered the out-of-order back-end.  The store-address uop only reads %rdx and %rax, so it has a RAW dependency on the `addq $1, %rax` in the previous iteration, assuming this is a loop.)

So line 5 has a RAW dependency on line 4, and is not *directly* dependent on line 2 in any way.  (The load was earlier in the dependency chain leading to the store, but separated from it by going through the `addsd`.)

---

If `.L6` is somewhere before `.L3` so this is a loop, there's a [WAR anti-dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_(computer_architecture)#Data_hazards) between the store at the bottom and the load in the next iteration, into XMM0.

See also

- [Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables? (Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113527/why-does-mulss-take-only-3-cycles-on-haswell-different-from-agners-instruction)  - how register renaming avoids WAW and WAR hazards
- [Deoptimizing a program for the pipeline in Intel Sandybridge-family CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361145/deoptimizing-a-program-for-the-pipeline-in-intel-sandybridge-family-cpus) - includes the same point, and also for memory via store-forwarding.

Comment: thanks for the response haha saving me the agony of confusion :) 
as a follow-up to the question I had, given these dependencies, would it be safe to conclude that the iterative dependent registers in this case is %xmm0, %rdx and %rax? Or am i mistaken and it should be %xmm0 and %rax only? Confused about the movsd %xmm0, (%rdx,%rax,8) line, using rdx as a destination register.

Comment: @MeganDarcy: RDX is never written inside the loop. (Or is this not the whole loop?  Is there a modification to RDX somewhere outside the part we can see?  Where's `.L6`?)    Memory *pointed-to* by RDX and RAX is written to, but a store instruction (and the store-address uop) only reads registers, writes [the store-buffer entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141366/can-a-speculatively-executed-cpu-branch-contain-opcodes-that-access-ram).

Comment: apologies I made a typo, .L6 is actually the first part of the asm we see. I have edited accordingly :)

Comment: so given the edit, would that mean that %rdx is written in the loop? because the c code (which I will also edit in) shows the variable getting assigned to repeatedly.

Comment: @MeganDarcy: No, like I just said, none of the instructions in the question modify the RDX register, only read it (to use it as a memory address).  If there had been an `add $4096, %rdx` earlier in the loop (in a part you'd left out), then there'd be RAW (and WAR across iterations) hazards between that and the addressing modes that read RDX.

Comment: so this line movsd %xmm0, (%rdx,%rax,8) like you said earlier, is actually moving the value of %xmm0 into the memory pointed to by (%rdx,%rax,8) ?

Comment: @MeganDarcy: Yes, of course.  In AT&T syntax, `(...)` is a memory operand.  Just like in your C code, `double *P` is RDX, and P is never modified, only memory pointed-to through P.

Comment: okay perfect, thank you so much for being so patient with me hahaha ;)

Comment: @MeganDarcy: And BTW, this asm is a really inefficient implementation of it, I guess because there's no `restrict` qualifier and the compiler didn't check for overlap between `P[]` and `a[]` and make a version that keeps the running total in a register.  Putting a store/reload as part of the loop carried dependency instead of `P[i] = (sum += a[i])` makes this prefix sum take about twice as long as it should, even without using SIMD. ([SIMD prefix sum on Intel cpu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10587598))