# Outer-loop vectorization with SSE and NEON

Tags: vectorization, simd, sse, neon

I want to vectorize the following loop on ARM NEON and SSE:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
   b[i][0] = 0.0;
   for (int j = 1; j < n; ++j) {
      b[i][j] = b[i][j - 1] + a[i][j]; 
   }
}
```

This loop has a loop-carried dependency, so it cannot be vectorized simply. Instead, it can be vectorized using [outer-loop vectorization](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/outer-loop-vectorization.html).

Under the assumption that `a` and `b` are float32, outer-loop vectorization functions by running 4 instances of the inner loop in parallel. Here is what the iterations of the vectorized loop look like:

```
First iteration:  { { i = 0, j = 1 }, { i = 1, j = 1 }, { i = 2, j = 1 }, { i = 3 , j = 1 } }
Second iteration: { { i = 0, j = 2 }, { i = 1, j = 2 }, { i = 2, j = 2 }, { i = 3 , j = 2 } }

Etc.
```

I want to vectorize this loop using NEON and SSE. Neither of them support gathers and scatters, which are needed to simply vectorize this loop. Do you have any idea how to vectorize this loop efficiently?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to change the storage order of `a` and `b`. If you can't do that, you can either temporarily transpose blocks of `a` add them together and transpose them before storing them to `b`. Alternatively, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587598/simd-prefix-sum-on-intel-cpu/

Comment: SVE2, Neon's successor supports gathers and scatters. But chtz's solution to change storage order is the best one - you need to shape the data for parallelism, not just the algorithm

Comment: You can *unroll* the outer loop to hide latency bottlenecks in the inner loop, but with this data layout in memory, you'd have to shuffle data in and out of vectors, or transpose each block twice, around each vertical SIMD addition.  Shuffles aren't cheaper than addition.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm which you have in your code is called “exclusive prefix sum”.

I’m not sure SIMD going to bring much profit, but still, about SSE, try the following version. Micro-kernel:

```
// Given a vector of [ a, b, c, d ], compute a vector of [ a, a+b, a+b+c, a+b+c+d ]
// The function requires SSE 4.1 support
__m128 inclusivePrefixSum( __m128 v )
{
    // a*2, a+b, c*2, c+d
    __m128 tmp = _mm_add_ps( v, _mm_moveldup_ps( v ) );
    // a, a+b, c, c+d
    tmp = _mm_blend_ps( tmp, v, 0b0101 );

    // Broadcasted a+b
    __m128 res = _mm_shuffle_ps( tmp, tmp, _MM_SHUFFLE( 1, 1, 1, 1 ) );
    // a*2+b, (a+b)*2, a+b+c, a+b+c+d
    res = _mm_add_ps( res, tmp );
    // a, a+b, a+b+c, a+b+c+d
    res = _mm_blend_ps( res, tmp, 0b0011 );
    return res;
}
```

Usage:

```
    const size_t innerEndAligned = 1 + ( ( n - 1 ) / 4 ) * 4;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        float* const pa = a[ i ];
        float* const pb = b[ i ];

        __m128 acc = _mm_setzero_ps();
        _mm_store_ss( pb, acc );
        size_t j;
        for( j = 1; j < innerEndAligned; j += 4 )
        {
            // Load 4 elements
            __m128 vec = _mm_loadu_ps( pa + j );
            // Compute prefix sum
            vec = inclusivePrefixSum( vec );
            // Increment by the accumulator
            vec = _mm_add_ps( vec, acc );
            // Store 4 output elements
            _mm_storeu_ps( pb + j, vec );
            // Broadcast the last lane from the vector,
            // which contains cumulative sum of the row so far, into the accumulator
            acc = _mm_shuffle_ps( vec, vec, _MM_SHUFFLE( 3, 3, 3, 3 ) );
        }

        // Handle the last 0-3 elements of the row with scalar code
        for( ; j < n; j++ )
        {
            __m128 v = _mm_load_ss( pa + j );
            acc = _mm_add_ss( acc, v );
            _mm_store_ss( pb + j, acc );
        }
    }
```

Comment: For prefix sums, working in larger chunks lets you hide more latency.  See a comment on [parallel prefix (cumulative) sum with SSE](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/126788986)  But even with one vector at once, there's something to be gained vs. the bad latency of pure serial.  Or in this case, maybe unroll over the outer loop, interleaving work on two or four `i` values in parallel.