# Elliminating a backward dependence

Tags: c, loops, optimization, vectorization

I have an encryption algorithm that has the structure of

```c
uint8_t state = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    state = data[i] ^ state;
    data[i] = state;
}
```

And a corresponding decryption algorithm:

```c
uint8_t state = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    uint8_t prev = state;
    state = data[i];
    data[i] ^= prev;
}
```

(Note: that is not the actual algorithm, only the structure that is relevant for this question)

The nice thing about the decryption algorithm is that it has no backward dependencies and so the compiler outputs vectorized code.

However, the encryption algorithm is dependent on the previous state to figure out the next state and this causes a backward dependency.

Is there some "trick" to remove this dependency?

I tried to read about it online, but all resources that I could find just mention that if you have a backward dependency then the loop can't be vectorized but none of them mentioned if there are some tricks for some specific cases where backward dependence can be eliminated.

As such, if in this case the dependence can't be eliminated, is there some heuristic one can use to analyze if a backward dependence could be eliminated?

Comment: I don't think so. The encryption algorithm is "chained", it's intentionally designed to make each step dependent on that previous data.

Comment: `decryption algorithm is that it has no backward dependencies` why do you think so?

Comment: Using a dependency graph, all arrows point forward. Meanwhile in the encryption algorithm there is an arrow that points to itself. Also the compiler is successful in vectorizing it

Comment: can you provide these dependency graphs for code you posted?

Comment: The only dependency that exists in the decryption outside the loop boundary is that line 3 is dependent on line 4

Comment: either you're misreading output from your tool or it just wrong, both these functions cannot be vectorized because both of them to calculate each byte have dependency on previously calculated one

Comment: I did the dependency graph by hand. A backward dependency isn't a dependency on the previous loop iteration: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/requirements-for-vectorizable-loops.html.

Comment: `There should be no backward loop-carried dependencies. For example, the loop must not require statement 2 of iteration 1 to be executed before statement 1 of iteration 2 for correct results.`  this is exactly situation in decrypt function

Comment: `state = data[i];` from iteration 1 must be executed before `uint8_t prev = state;` of iteration 2

Comment: Oh, I got those mixed up, still the compiler is successful in vectorizing it, how come?

Comment: can you post vectorized code?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/nEPdr1o31. Edit: add -Rpass=loop-vectorize -Rpass-missed=loop-vectorize to the compiler flags and indeed it even notices that the vectorization was successful

Comment: it looks like in second case clang was able to derive formula, which removed prev variable from equation and thus backward dependency, basically it unrolled it to `data[15]^=data[14]^data[13]..data[0]^0; data[14]^=data[13]^...data[0]^0;` and so on

Comment: So there definitely  are cases which backward dependence can be eliminated, the question is if there is some sort of criteria to "quickly" figure out if it is possible

Comment: basically your question is "can arbitrary algorithm with backward dependency be replaced with another algorithm with the same visible result without backward dependency"? I suppose this question is somewhere around p(!)=np problem which has no solution

Comment: anyway, in this particular scenario - I'd say yes, it is possible to remove backward dependency for encrypt as well, just need to generate the same formula for each element, ie `...;data[2]^=data[1]^data[0]^state; data[1] ^= data[0] ^ state;`

Comment: Thanks! while this solves this particular issue, I was interested if there are "known algorithm classes" that do have this property, i.e. are there some specific algorithms (not general ones) that hold certain criteria for which we can always find an equivalent algorithm without a dependence.

Comment: theoretically - yes, you can derive very long formula for each element, which does not have any dependency, but also note - even vectorized decrypt still has dependency `movdqa  xmm0, xmm2` preserves calculated 16 bytes to re-use on next iteration

Comment: "are there some specific algorithms (not general ones) that hold certain criteria for which we can always find an equivalent algorithm without a dependence" - the term for this is "recurrence relation" and there is significant mathematical research on the topic

Comment: The way you describe your problem you have a prefix sum (just with `xor` instead of `add`, which has a duplicate e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587598/simd-prefix-sum-on-intel-cpu (and for `xor` 0 happens to be the neutral element as well, i.e., you can simply replace `add` by `xor`). If your actual algorithm is only "similar" it is hard to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. AES-GCM does exactly that.

At some level it can be considered a one-time-pad, which is generated using a counter-based pseudo random generator. That is, every block or byte to be decrypted/encrypted can be independently produced from a hard-to-invert transformation from position or offset of the block to be ciphered.

```
  C(i) = M(i) ^ OneWayFunction(i, key); 
  M(i) = C(i) ^ OneWayFunction(i, key);
```

AES can be of course combined with many other chaining modes and even without chaining (ECB-mode, which infamously fails to hide the overall shape of vector graphic images...).

Comment: So your suggestion is changing the algorithm, unfortunately I can't do that as this is a reimplemention of some library that needs the same results.

Comment: Well, it's a bit difficult to answer to your exact problem, if it's not even disclosed :)
Conceptual level might not be enough, until we can verify that the problem is actually equivalent to cumulative xor, which can be optimised with SIMD (using O(log2 BlockSize) operations).