# numpy array TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, vectorization

```
i=np.arange(1,4,dtype=np.int)
a=np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
```

and

```
a
>>>array([[0, 1, 2],
          [3, 4, 5],
          [6, 7, 8]])
a[:,0:1]
>>>array([[0],
          [3],
          [6]])
a[:,0:2]
>>>array([[0, 1],
          [3, 4],
          [6, 7]])
a[:,0:3]
>>>array([[0, 1, 2],
          [3, 4, 5],
          [6, 7, 8]])
```

Now I want to vectorize the array to print them all together. I try

```
a[:,0:i]
```

or

```
a[:,0:i[:,None]]
```

It gives TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Answer (score 47):

I ran into the problem when venturing to use numpy.concatenate to emulate a C++ like pushback for 2D-vectors; If A and B are two 2D numpy.arrays, then numpy.concatenate(A,B) yields the error.

The fix was to simply to add the **missing brackets**: numpy.concatenate( **(** A,B **)** ), which are required because the arrays to be concatenated constitute to a *single* argument

Answer (score 40):

Short answer:

```
[a[:,:j] for j in i]
```

---

What you are trying to do is *not a vectorizable operation*. [Wikipedia defines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming) vectorization as a batch operation on a single array, instead of on individual scalars:

> In computer science, array programming languages (also known as vector or multidimensional languages) generalize operations on scalars to apply transparently to vectors, matrices, and higher-dimensional arrays.
>
> ...
>
> ... an operation that operates on entire arrays can be called a **vectorized** operation...

In terms of CPU-level optimization, the [definition of vectorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422149/what-is-vectorization) is:

> "Vectorization" (simplified) is the process of rewriting a loop so that instead of processing a single element of an array N times, it processes (say) 4 elements of the array simultaneously N/4 times.

The problem with your case is that the result of each individual operation has a *different shape*: `(3, 1)`, `(3, 2)` and `(3, 3)`. They can not form the output of a single vectorized operation, because the output has to be one contiguous array. Of course, it can contain `(3, 1)`, `(3, 2)` and `(3, 3)` arrays inside of it (as views), but that's what your original array `a` already does.

What you're really looking for is just a single expression that computes all of them:

```
[a[:,:j] for j in i]
```

... but it's not vectorized in a sense of performance optimization. Under the hood it's plain old `for` loop that computes each item one by one.

Comment: Cant tell you ho grateful I am, thank you. Saved my days

Comment: This is not the answer I wanted, but was the one I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

This could be unrelated to this specific problem, but I ran into a similar issue where I used NumPy indexing on a Python list and got the same exact error message:

```
# incorrect
weights = list(range(1, 129)) + list(range(128, 0, -1))
mapped_image = weights[image[:, :, band]] # image.shape = [800, 600, 3]
# TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

It turns out I needed to turn `weights`, a 1D Python list, into a NumPy array before I could apply multi-dimensional NumPy indexing. The code below works:

```
# correct
weights = np.array(list(range(1, 129)) + list(range(128, 0, -1)))
mapped_image = weights[image[:, :, band]] # image.shape = [800, 600, 3]
```

Answer (score 13):

try the following to change your array to 1D

```
a.reshape((1, -1))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48513824/compute-mfcc-for-varying-time-intervals-based-on-time-stamps I have similar error how do I address it.

Answer (score 8):

You can use numpy.ravel to return a flattened array from n-dimensional array:

```
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>> a.ravel()
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem and solved it using list...not sure if this will help or not

```
classes = list(unique_labels(y_true, y_pred))
```

Comment: You're right...unfortunately I'm not quite sure how it was solved...I had a working example and when I compared the output of example vs my code I found that the example code in this line was generating a list of items...so I thought of making mine a list too and that fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

this problem arises when we use vectors in place of scalars 
for example in a for loop the range should be a scalar, in case you have given a vector in that place you get error. So to avoid the problem use the length of the vector you have used

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this error when while trying to access elements of a list using a 1-D array. I was suggested this page but I don't the answer I was looking for.

Let `l` be the list and `myarray` be my 1D array. The correct way to access list `l` using elements of `myarray` is

`np.take(l,myarray)`