# TypeError when indexing a list with a NumPy array: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

The following code:

```
x = list(range(0,10))
random.shuffle(x)
ind = np.argsort(x)
x[ind]
```

produces the error: TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Note that my problem is different than in the question, 
"[numpy array TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902367/numpy-array-typeerror-only-integer-scalar-arrays-can-be-converted-to-a-scalar-i)", which is attempting something more complex.

My mistake in this question is that I'm trying to use a list of indexes on an ordinary python list -- see my answer. I expect it happens much more broadly than  just with using range and shuffle.

Comment: You could also just use `np.arange(0,10)` instead of `list(range(0,10))`

Comment: Let me get it right. By doing so, the output will still be the same as your original `x` which is `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`. Do you agree?

Comment: @Bazingaa That is correct. The point of this question is to illustrate a common way of producing the error "only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

Comment: @sacul Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't know about that function. The point of this question is to illustrate a common way of producing the error "only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

Comment: You used to be able to do this. I think it's a python 3 change, and not a numpy change, but I don't know for sure. I came here because I have old code in py2.7 and I traced a bug to `range(200)[np.array((119,), dtype=int)]`, where `np.array((119,), dtype=int)` is short for `index = np.where(some_complicated_thing == some_complicated_other_thing)` This worked in py2.7 and in older versions of numpy, as long as the conversion to an integer index was legal. You might be doing this for old habits reasons too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that I am attempting to index `x`, an ordinary Python list, as if it were a numpy array. To fix it, simply convert `x` to a numpy array:

```
x = list(range(0,10))
random.shuffle(x)
ind = np.argsort(x)
x = np.array(x) # This is the key line
x[ind]
```

(This has happened to me twice now.)

Answer (score 2):

Good answer - but I would add that if the list cannot be converted to a numpy array (i.e. you have a list of string) you cannot slice it with an array of indices as described above. The most straightforward alternative is

`[x[i] for i in ind]`