# What is the function of np.nonzero with slicing a np.array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

you all! I have very specific question about np.nonzero and it's function while slicing a np.array (First of all, I am not 100% sure it is called slicing). I found a Python script on the internet and get an error at the following line:

```
if (i in dividendsStep):
   div = dividends[1][np.nonzero(dividendsStep == (i))[0]]
   currentDividend = currentDividend + div
```

And I get the following error:

```
div = dividends[1][np.nonzero(dividendsStep == (i))[0]]
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

When I drop np.nonzero(x), it doesn't generate the error but it does not generate the right answer (I know the input variables and what the answer should be).

When I print the np.nonzero part, I get the following output:

```
print(np.nonzero(dividendsStep==(i)))
(array([0], dtype=int32),)
```

When I print dividends, I get the following output

```py
print(dividends)
[[0.2917], [2.06]]
```

Furthermore I think it is a python 2 script (I had to replace xrange for range). I don't know if it's relevant when I try the same code in a Python 2.7 interpreter I get the same error.

**Question**

What is the function of np.nonzero in the slicing? I know it returns the indices of the elements that are non-zero but it doesn't make sense in this 'slice'. If it is called different, please let me know, I will update it right away!

**Answer**

Ubuntu has provided the answer:

```
dividends=np.array(dividends)
```

Comment: What kind of object is `dividends[1]`? If `type(dividends[1])` returns `list`, then see [TypeError when trying to use list of integers in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51638332/190597).

Comment: @unutbu if I print type, I get the following error: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable. When I print(dividends), I got two lists in a list. I will take a look at your suggestion. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @unutbu I also updated the question, so you can see the printout

Comment: nonzero gives a tuple of arrays. Here it is 1 array which [0] extracts.  Looks like `dividends` is a list of lists.  Lists can only be indexed with an integer, or something that can turned into one.