# Only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index not running under Spyder

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv, yolo

I have the following code, which runs well under Visual Studio Code with python 3.9.10, opencv 4.5.5 and numpy 1.22.1.

I would like to migrate this code into the Spyder IDE (Version 5, another notebook), python 3.8, opencv 4.5.1 and numpy 1.22.2.

In spyder, I get the error message TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted a scalar index in line: output_layers = [layer_names[i-1]...] (marked line down in the code section)

I have already checked other answers on this site such as
[TypeError when indexing a list with a NumPy array: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51638332/typeerror-when-indexing-a-list-with-a-numpy-array-only-integer-scalar-arrays-ca)
which suggests list comprehension, but in my understanding I am already implemented this.

What is the reason for running currectly in on environment but not in the other?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def get_output_layers(net):
   layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
```

> output_layers = [layer_names[i - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]

```
   return output_layers


def draw_prediction(img, class_id, confidence, x, y, x_plus_w, y_plus_h):

   label = str(classes[class_id])

   color = COLORS[class_id]

cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x_plus_w,y_plus_h), color, 2)

cv2.putText(img, label, (x-10,y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, color, 2)


image = cv2.imread('horses.jpg')

Width = image.shape[1]
Height = image.shape[0]
scale = 0.00392

classes = None

with open(r'yolov3.txt', 'r') as f:
   classes = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

COLORS = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(classes), 3))

net = cv2.dnn.readNet('yolov3.weights','yolov3.cfg')
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, scale, (416,416), (0,0,0), True, crop=False)
net.setInput(blob)

outs = net.forward(get_output_layers(net))
class_ids = []
confidences = []
boxes = []
conf_threshold = 0.5
nms_threshold = 0.4



for out in outs:
   for detection in out:
    scores = detection[5:]
    class_id = np.argmax(scores)
    confidence = scores[class_id]
    if confidence > 0.5:
        center_x = int(detection[0] * Width)
        center_y = int(detection[1] * Height)
        w = int(detection[2] * Width)
        h = int(detection[3] * Height)
        x = center_x - w / 2
        y = center_y - h / 2
        class_ids.append(class_id)
        confidences.append(float(confidence))
        boxes.append([x, y, w, h])


indices = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, conf_threshold, nms_threshold)

for i in indices:

   box = boxes[i]
   x = box[0]
   y = box[1]
   w = box[2]
   h = box[3]
  draw_prediction(image, class_ids[i], confidences[i], round(x), round(y), 
  round(x+w), round(y+h))

cv2.imshow("object detection", image)
cv2.waitKey()

cv2.imwrite("object-detection.jpg", image)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

there were subtle, recent api changes wrt handling `std::vector` in python

(4.5.1 still expects a 2d array, but it's 1d in 4.5.5)

to avoid the whole trouble, please simply use:

```
output_layers = net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames()
```

(like it is done in [the sample](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/samples/dnn/object_detection.py#L92))