# python - applying a mask to an array in a for loop

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have this code:

```
import numpy as np

result = {}
result['depth'] = [1,1,1,2,2,2]
result['generation'] = [1,1,1,2,2,2]
result['dimension'] = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
result['data'] = [np.array([0,0,0]), np.array([0,0,0]), np.array([0,0,0]), np.array([0,0,0]), np.array([0,0,0]), np.array([0,0,0])]

for v in np.unique(result['depth']):
    temp_v = (result['depth'] ==  v)
    values_v = [result[string][temp_v] for string in result.keys()]
    this_v = dict(zip(result.keys(), values_v))
```

in which I want to create a new `dict`called '`this_v`', with the same keys as the original dict `result`, but fewer values.

The line:

```
values_v = [result[string][temp_v] for string in result.keys()]
```

gives an error

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

which I don't understand, since I can create  `ex = result[result.keys()[0]][temp_v]` just fine. It just does not let me do this with a for loop so that I can fill the list.

Any idea as to why it does not work?

Comment: Keep in mind that all of your dict values are lists, not NumPy arrays. Converting them to proper NumPy arrays may change some things.

Comment: Just add `np.array` for you dict values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve your problem (finding and dropping duplicates) I encourage you to use `pandas`. It is a Python module that makes your life absurdly simple:

```
import numpy as np

result = {}
result['depth'] = [1,1,1,2,2,2]
result['generation'] = [1,1,1,2,2,2]
result['dimension'] = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
result['data'] = [np.array([0,0,0]), np.array([0,0,0]), np.array([0,0,0]),\
         np.array([0,0,0]), np.array([0,0,0]), np.array([0,0,0])]

# Here comes pandas!
import pandas as pd

# Converting your dictionary of lists into a beautiful dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(result)

#>    data         depth dimension generation
# 0     [0, 0, 0]   1       1        1
# 1     [0, 0, 0]   1       2        1
# 2     [0, 0, 0]   1       3        1
# 3     [0, 0, 0]   2       1        2
# 4     [0, 0, 0]   2       2        2
# 5     [0, 0, 0]   2       3        2


# Dropping duplicates... in one single command!
df = df.drop_duplicates('depth')

#>    data         depth dimension generation
# 0     [0, 0, 0]   1       1        1
# 3     [0, 0, 0]   2       1        2
```

If you want oyur data back in the original format... you need yet again just one line of code!

```
df.to_dict('list')

#> {'data': [array([0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0])],
#   'depth': [1, 2],
#   'dimension': [1, 1],
#   'generation': [1, 2]}
```

Comment: Pandas has become my new religion!