# A Tensorflow issue while building a CNN model: TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I have an idea to build an image dataset with corresponding label.
First, I convert the image of PNG format into tensor.

```
total = 100
image_list = np.empty(shape=(total, 128, 128, 3))
for i in tqdm(range(total)):
    file_path = f"./STFT_spectra/STFT_spectra{i}.png"
    image = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    image = tf.io.decode_png(image, channels=3)
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)

    image = tf.image.resize(image, [128, 128])
    image_list[i] = image

pickle.dump(image_list, open("image_list.p", "wb"))
```

Then, I converted labels into dataset. In my case, each ground truth is a list. Like [0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.3, 0.7]. And a bunch of labels are also stored as ".p" file.

```
 pickle.dump(labels, open("labels.p", "wb"))
```

Next, the dataset was generated.

```
labels = pickle.load(open(".././labels.p", "rb"))
print("1")
print(labels)
print("2")
print(type(labels))
print(labels.shape)
fetched_image_list = pickle.load(open("../image_list.p", "rb"))
print("3")
print(fetched_image_list.shape)
print(type(fetched_image_list))
fetched_image_list = tf.convert_to_tensor(fetched_image_list)
print("4")
print(dataset)
print(len(dataset))
```

In order to visualise the basic information of each variable, I printed all of them.

```
1
[[0.89183587 0.16114736 0.94493681 ... 0.14511068 0.37336048 0.49724814]
 [0.17122088 0.94086313 0.98345256 ... 0.22023985 0.72931111 0.73559833]
 [0.50994694 0.11969627 0.19911897 ... 0.218943   0.70127559 0.03944503]
 ...
 [0.43770069 0.85309672 0.46241647 ... 0.61051947 0.447418   0.45685247]
 [0.06972272 0.7845251  0.21700071 ... 0.03850145 0.07945128 0.6375879 ]
 [0.020571   0.8400135  0.01419005 ... 0.57517469 0.45426425 0.84025627]]
2
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(100, 155)
2022-07-06 02:58:49.112016: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
3
(100, 128, 128, 3)
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>
4
<TensorSliceDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(128, 128, 3), dtype=tf.float64, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(155,), dtype=tf.float64, name=None))>
100
```

My CNN model goes like this:

```
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=(2,2), padding="same", dilation_rate=(1,1), input_shape=fetched_image_list[1:], activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(71, (3, 3), strides=(2,2), padding="same", dilation_rate=(1,1), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 4), strides=(2,3), padding="same", dilation_rate=(1,1),activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), strides=(2,2), padding="same", dilation_rate=(1,1),activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 4), strides=(2, 3), padding="same", dilation_rate=(1, 1), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same", dilation_rate=(1, 1), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.20),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(label_size)
])
```

It looks good, but when I ran my code, it popped out this error:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

My questions are:

- So how can I fix this issue? Is there any wrong configuration within the process?
- Did the process of assembling dataset correct?

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Comment: Hi @TerrySoki, This generally happens when NumPy indexing is applied on a Python list. Kindly refer to this similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902367/numpy-array-typeerror-only-integer-scalar-arrays-can-be-converted-to-a-scalar-i). Thank you!