# What’s the difference between the two operations in back-propagation with pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a tensor x and `x.shape=(batch_size,10)`

I want to add one to all of the elements, and take two different operations

1. `x=x+1`
2. `for i in range(0,batch_size):
     x[i]=x[i]+1`

I got the same tensors with the two operations,but when I call `loss.backward()`, (2) takes much more time than (1) in back propagation.

What’s the difference between them???

Answer (score 0):

This is to be expected. Firstly, the forward is also a lot slower: with your `for` loop, Python dispatches `batch_size` times the following requests to PyTorch:

1. fetch `i`th element of `x`
2. add 1
3. update `i`th element of `x` with the incremented value

Python is slow. In version two,  Python dispatches a single message "add 1 everywhere" to PyTorch. PyTorch is much faster than Python (let alone GPU acceleration it's capable of). This is thanks to the technique called [vectorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422149/what-is-vectorization) and is not specific to PyTorch, but essentially all Python (and many other) math packages.

Secondly, for your backward, PyTorch needs to keep track of all operations which happened to `x` and backpropagate through them. In the first case, there's `batch_size` of them, in the second, just one. Again, vectorization wins.

Comment: Thanks for your answer，and I try to take
(3). for i in range(0,batch_size):x=x+1 (4). for i in range(0,batch_size):x+=1. I found (2) still took much more time than (3).and (4) is nearly as slow as (2) in back-propagation,The time they spend is:(4)>=(2)>>(3)>=(1). Is there any difference between the computation graph they create? It seems that (2) and (4) is an in-place operation, does the result is related to this?

Comment: I am honestly lost in your labeling of operations. What is (2)?

Computation graphs record all pytorch operations on tensors with `requires_grad=True` (or at least you can assume they do, they may optimize things away but treat that as an implementation detail). Yes, there is difference between `x = x + 1` and `x += 1`. The latter is in-place, the former is not (it looks as if it were, but it's redefining `x` rather than mutating it).

Comment: I mean if i replace x[i]=x[i]+1 in(2) with x+=1, the speed of back-propagation is nearly as slow as  x[i]=x[i]+1,but if I replace it with x=x+1, it's amost as quick as (1) in back-propagation. So I was thinking the speed of (2) may be related to the in-place operation,as x[i]=x[i]+1 and x+=1 are both in-place operation.

Comment: I'm lost what your goal is. Executing `x[i] = x[i] + 1` in a loop is not equivalent mathematically to executing `x = x + 1` in a loop. In the first, you add 1 to each entry of `x`, in the second you add 1 to the _whole_ `x` `batch_size` times, so it's equivalent to executing `x[i] = x[i] + batch_size` in a loop. In terms of computation graphs those are all different. If you are looking to optimize some specific operation, consider asking a new question. If you're just looking to find the difference between the back-prop in this case, I think I've explained all there is to it.