# backward count in a numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's suppose I have a series of integer values arranged in a numpy array like this.

```
nan = np.nan
arr = np.array([3, nan, nan, nan, 5, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])
```

`nan` values should be filled with backward count from the first not null value to zero.

```
[3, 2, 1, 0, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Does pandas also work?

Comment: yeah absolutely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a vectorized one with NumPy -

```
def backward_count(a):
    m = ~np.isnan(a)
    idx = np.flatnonzero(m)

    p = np.full(len(a), -1, dtype=a.dtype)
    p[idx[0]] = a[idx[0]]+idx[0]

    d = np.diff(idx)
    p[idx[1:]] = np.diff(a[m]) + d - 1
    out = p.cumsum()
    out[:idx[0]] = np.nan
    return out
```

Sample run with a more generic case -

```
In [238]: a
Out[238]: array([nan,  3., nan,  5., nan, 10., nan, nan,  4., nan, nan])

In [239]: backward_count(a)
Out[239]: array([nan,  3.,  2.,  5.,  4., 10.,  9.,  8.,  4.,  3.,  2.])
```

#### Benchmarking

Setup with scaling up the given sample by `10,000x` -

```
In [240]: arr = np.array([3, nan, nan, nan, 5, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])

In [241]: arr = np.tile(arr,10000)

# Pandas based one by @cs95
In [243]: %%timeit
     ...: s = pd.Series(np.cumsum(~np.isnan(arr)))
     ...: s.groupby(s).cumcount(ascending=False)
35.9 ms ± 258 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [245]: %timeit backward_count(arr)
3.04 ms ± 4.35 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 8):

IMO, the simplest pandas way of doing this is using `groupby` and `cumcount` with `ascending=False`:

```
s = pd.Series(np.cumsum(~np.isnan(arr)))
s.groupby(s).cumcount(ascending=False)

0    3
1    2
2    1
3    0
4    5
5    4
6    3
7    2
8    1
9    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: @QuangHoang Sorry, not sure I follow. It labels rows within each group with a (decreasing) count.

Comment: sorry, I must have been day-dreaming. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

arr = pd.Series([3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,5,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan])

for i in range(len(arr)):
    # Check if each element is "NaN"
    if math.isnan(arr[i]):
        # If NaN then take the previous element and subtract 1
        arr[i] = arr[i-1]-1

# print the final array
print(arr)
```

Result:

```
0    3.0
1    2.0
2    1.0
3    0.0
4    5.0
5    4.0
6    3.0
7    2.0
8    1.0
9    0.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: 1) you have not explained your code (yes, it is obvious to me but not to everyone who reads it), and 2) using loops with numpy is a no-no.

Comment: I'm new to numpy myself, why are loops bad?

Comment: NumPy operations are implemented to be faster and more scalable than loops. The process is called ["vectorisation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422149/what-is-vectorization) and is a few steps above loops in terms of performance.