# Return percentage counts of select values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have current code and then a print output that is a series as below

```
shapes = ['triangle','circle','square']
max_shape = None
max_percent = None
for shape in shapes:
    df_overall = df[(df['Shape']== shape)]
    num_overall = df_overall.shape[0]
    shape_df = df
    num_total = shape_df.shape[0]
    percentage_overall = num_overall / num_total


    if max_shape is None: 



        print(shape, percentage_overall)
```

It gives me the percentage of each value in the shape column as a series,

```
triangle 0.672
circle 0.16
square 0.168
```

Can I instead of printing to a series can I retrieve the output as a dataframe instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ditch the loop, you may vectorize this via `value_counts`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Shape': ['triangle'] * 3 + ['square'] * 2 + ['trapezoid'] * 5})
shapes = ['triangle', 'square']
```

```
df.loc[df['Shape'].isin(shapes), 'Shape'].value_counts().div(len(df)).to_frame() 

          Shape
triangle    0.3
square      0.2
```

The "can I output this as a frame and not a series" is a trivial problem solved by calling `to_frame()` on the result.

Comment: Thnx, when you say it vectorizes can you explain that for the value counts?

Comment: @Chris90 are you familiar with the concept of [vectorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422149/what-is-vectorization) itself? What you did was to manually run a loop to count each shape and get its percentage. By "vectorizing" this operation, you are essentially counting all the shapes at once. That's a 10,000 foot explanation but essentially you treat your data as a whole rather than as individual data points.