# c++20 execution policy type

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

I've been getting into standard algorithms and noticed that you can specify an execution policy.

The documentation found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t) lists 4 policies:

```
std::execution::sequenced_policy  
std::execution::parallel_policy 
std::execution::parallel_unsequenced_policy  
std::execution::unsequenced_policy
```

I understand the difference between parallel policies and sequenced ones, but I'm not sure why you'd also need unsequenced and unsequenced parallel?

From what I know you can't guarantee thread execution order anyway so wouldn't that make the parallel and parallel unsequenced policies identical?

Why add a normal unsequenced policy when if you can't parallelise the policy automatically falls back to a sequential one?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Table Visualization**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   Type                  |     Vectorization     |     Parallelization |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------                
| Sequenced               |           X           |           X         | 
| Unsequenced             |           V           |           X         |
| Parallel                |           X           |           V         |
| Parallel & unsequenced  |           V           |           V         |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

From latest C++20 working draft [n4849](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf)

> 20.18 Execution policies 
>   An object of an execution policy type indicates the kinds of
>   parallelism allowed in the execution of an algorithm and expresses the
>   consequent requirements on the element access functions.

```
using namespace std;
vector<int> v = /* ... */;

// standard sequential sort
sort(v.begin(), v.end());

// explicitly sequential sort
sort(execution::seq, v.begin(), v.end());

// permitting parallel execution
sort(execution::par, v.begin(), v.end());

// permitting vectorization as well
sort(execution::par_unseq, v.begin(), v.end());
```

**§ 20.18.3 Execution policy type trait**

- 20.18.4 Sequenced execution policy  [execpol.seq]

  1. The class execution::sequenced_policy is an execution policy type
     used as a unique type to disambiguate parallel algorithm overloading
     and require that a parallel algorithm’s execution **may not** be
     **parallelized**.

---

- 20.18.5 Parallel execution policy [execpol.par]

  1. The class execution::parallel_policy is an execution policy type used as a unique type to disambiguate parallel algorithm overloading and indicate that a parallel algorithm’s execution **may be**
     **parallelized**.

---

- 20.18.6 Parallel and unsequenced execution policy [execpol.parunseq]

  1. The class execution::parallel_unsequenced_policy is an execution policy type used as a unique
     type to disambiguate parallel algorithm overloading and indicate that a parallel algorithm’s execution **may be parallelized and vectorized**.

---

- 20.18.7 Unsequenced execution policy [execpol.unseq]

  1. The class unsequenced_policy is an execution policy type used as a unique type to disambiguate parallel
     algorithm overloading and indicate that a parallel algorithm’s execution **may be vectorized**, e.g., executed on
     a single thread using instructions that operate on multiple data items.

---

Further reading

- [What is vectorization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422149/what-is-vectorization)
- [Array Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming)
- [The Rise of Parallelism](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/vectorization-a-key-tool-to-improve-performance-on-modern-cpus)