# Vectorizing an iterative function on Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, vectorization

I have a dataframe where the first row is the initial condition.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Year": np.arange(4),
                   "Pop": [0.4] + [np.nan]* 3})
```

and a function `f(x,r) = r*x*(1-x)`, where `r = 2` is a constant and `0 <= x <= 1`.

I want to produce the following dataframe by applying the function to column `Pop` row-by-row iteratively. I.e., `df.Pop[i] = f(df.Pop[i-1], r=2)`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Year": np.arange(4),
                   "Pop": [0.4, 0.48, 4992, 0.49999872]})
```

**Question: Is it possible to do this in a vectorized way?**

I can achieve the desired result by using a loop to build lists for the x and y values, but this is not vectorized.

I have also tried this, but all `nan` places are filled with `0.48`.

```
df.loc[1:, "Pop"] = R * df.Pop[:-1] * (1 - df.Pop[:-1])
```

Comment: Can you give an example with data explaining the desired behavior.

Comment: The function is f(x) = r * x * (1 - x), where r is a constant and x is a percentage.  The first column is the starting conditions, where r = 2,x = 0.4, the index is the time interval.  d[0] would be (0, 0.4).  d[1] is  (1, 0.48).  d[2] should be (2, 0.4992), but it's (2, 0.48), the same as the remaining rows.

Comment: Non of your variables are defined in your code. Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with input data and expected output.

Comment: May you provide sample data in a [reproducible way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391) and the expected output?

Comment: You edited the correct example wrong. `np.arange(51)` gives error because the lengths of lists do not match. Please note that **the primary purpose of an example is for the potential helpers to reproduce your problem**, so focus on the relevant part only and simplify others as much as possible. I am editing your post currently. Please wait for it to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

It is IMPOSSIBLE to do this in a vectorized way.

By definition, vectorization makes use of parallel processing to reduce execution time. But the desired values in your question must be computed in *sequential* order, not in *parallel*. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1422181/3218693) for detailed explanation. Things like [df.expanding(2).apply(f)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) and [df.rolling(2).apply(f)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) won't work.

However, gaining more **efficiency** is possible. You can do the iteration using a generator. This is a very common construct for implementing iterative processes.

```
def gen(x_init, n, R=2):
    x = x_init
    for _ in range(n):
        x = R * x * (1-x)
        yield x

# execute            
df.loc[1:, "Pop"] = list(gen(df.at[0, "Pop"], len(df) - 1))
```

Result:

```
print(df)
        Pop
0  0.400000
1  0.480000
2  0.499200
3  0.499999
```

It is completely OK to stop here for small-sized data. If the function is going to be performed a lot of times, however, you can consider optimizing the generator with [numba](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/index.html).

- `pip install numba` or `conda install numba` in the console first
- `import numba`
- Add decorator `@numba.njit` in front of the generator.

Change the number of `np.nan`s to 10^6 and check out the difference in execution time yourself. An improvement from 468ms to 217ms was achieved on my Core-i5 8250U 64bit laptop.