# Add column to Pandas DataFrame created by function?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

There is a csv file with following urls inside:

```
1;https://www.one.de 
2;https://www.two.de 
3;https://www.three.de
4;https://www.four.de
5;https://www.five.de
```

Then I load it to a pandas dataframe df.

```
cols = ['nr','url']
df = pd.read_csv("listing.csv", sep=';', encoding = "utf8", dtype=str, names=cols)
```

Then I like to add another col 'domain_name' corresponding to the nr.

```
def takedn(url):
    m = urlsplit(url)
    return m.netloc.split('.')[-2]

df['domain_name'] = takedn(df['url'].all())
print(df.head())
```

But it takes the last domain_name for all nr's.

```
Output:
  nr                   url domain_name
0  1    https://www.one.de        five
1  2    https://www.two.de        five
2  3  https://www.three.de        five
3  4   https://www.four.de        five
4  5   https://www.five.de        five
```

I try this to learn vectorizing.
It will not work as I think. First line the domain_name should be one, second two and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To operate on element, you can use `apply()`.

```py
def takedn(url):
    m = urlsplit(url)
    return m.netloc.split('.')[-2]

df['domain_name'] = df['url'].apply(takedn)
```

Comment: Thanks, perfect answer. Is there a good tutorial or explanation for vectorization? Just for understanding.

Comment: @orgen Not know what do you mean by vectorization. But there is book called [Python for Data Analysis](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023784.do) teaching you how to use pandas to handle data.

Comment: Found a link here for vectorizing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422149/what-is-vectorization

Comment: @orgen That seems unrelated with pandas. But if you mainly want to apply functions on pandas. There are mainly three functions `apply`, `map` and `applymap`. For the difference among them, you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798153.

Answer (score 1):

We have built-in function in `tldextract`

```
import tldextract
df['domain'] = df.url.map(lambda x : tldextract.extract(x).domain)
df
   nr                   url domain_name domain
0   1    https://www.one.de        five    one
1   2    https://www.two.de        five    two
2   3  https://www.three.de        five  three
3   4   https://www.four.de        five   four
4   5   https://www.five.de        five   five
```