# Efficient grid approximation of likelihood in Julia

Tags: r, performance, statistics, julia

A simple approach of approximating the maximum likelihood of a model given some data is grid approximation. For example, in R, we can generate a grid of parameter values and then evaluate the likelihood of each value given some data (example from [Statistical Rethinking](https://xcelab.net/rm/statistical-rethinking/) by McElreath):

```
p_grid <- seq(from=0, to=1, length.out=1000)
likelihood <- dbinom(6, size=9, prob=p_grid)
```

Here, `likelihood` is an array of 1000 values and I assume this is an efficient way to get such an array.

I am new to Julia (and not so good at R) so my approach of doing the same as above relies on comprehension syntax:

```
using Distributions

p_grid = collect(LinRange(0, 1, 1000))
likelihood = [pdf(Binomial(n9=, p=p), 6) for p in p_grid]
```

which is not only clunky but somehow seems inefficient because a new Binomial gets constructed 1000 times. Is there a better, perhaps vectorized, approach to accomplishing the same task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In languages like R or Python, people often use the term "vectorization" to mean "avoid `for` loops in the language". I say "in the language" because there are still `for` loops, it's just that they're now in C instead of R/Python.

In Julia, there's nothing to worry about. You'll still sometimes hear "vectorization", but Julia folks tend to use this in the original sense  of hardware vectorization. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422149/what-is-vectorization).

As for your code, I think it's fine. To be sure, let's benchmark!

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime [pdf(Binomial(9, p), 6) for p in $p_grid]
  111.352 μs (1 allocation: 7.94 KiB)
```

Another way you could write this is using `map`:

```
julia> @btime map($p_grid) do p
           pdf(Binomial(9, p), 6)
           end;
  111.623 μs (1 allocation: 7.94 KiB)
```

To check for construction overhead, you could make lower-level calls to `StatsFuns`, like this

```
julia> using StatsFuns

julia> @btime map($p_grid) do p
           binompdf(9, p, 6)
           end;
  109.809 μs (1 allocation: 7.94 KiB)
```

It looks like there *some* difference, but it's pretty minor, maybe around 2% of the overall cost.